# How to get string objects instead of Unicode from JSON

Tags: python, json, serialization, unicode, python-2.x

I'm using **Python 2** to parse JSON from **ASCII encoded** text files.

When loading these files with either [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) or [`simplejson`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/), all my string values are cast to Unicode objects instead of string objects. The problem is, I have to use the data with some libraries that only accept string objects. I *can't change the libraries* nor update them.

Is it possible to get string objects instead of Unicode ones?

#### Example

```
>>> import json
>>> original_list = ['a', 'b']
>>> json_list = json.dumps(original_list)
>>> json_list
'["a", "b"]'
>>> new_list = json.loads(json_list)
>>> new_list
[u'a', u'b']  # I want these to be of type `str`, not `unicode`
```

(One easy and clean solution for 2017 is to use a recent version of Python — i.e. **Python 3** and forward.)

Comment: There is no problem under Python3, the type of items in new_list is `str`

Comment: Python 3k is not a 'recent version of Python' , it is just an alternative branch.

Comment: It's strange to see such comment in Dec 2017 - Python 2 is deprecated and no maintenance will happen after Jan 1 2020, which is less than 2 years: https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: @ZaarHai  LOT of people are stuck in Python 2 against their will.  There are many applications which embed their own Python version for automation and scripting so people have to use it until the vendor updates (I'm looking at you Maya, Houdini, Nuke..)

Comment: @Geordie I surely know and understand that. My comment was about terminology - Python is not an "alternative branch", but rather unfortunate lack of alternative (pun intended) for those who are stuck with it.

Comment: thanks a lot for the update! Saved me a lot of time

Comment: python 3 removed u' in my case while writing code in aws lambda

Answer (score 116, accepted):

#### A solution with `object_hook`

It works for both Python 2.7 **and** 3.x.

```
import json

def json_load_byteified(file_handle):
    return _byteify(
        json.load(file_handle, object_hook=_byteify),
        ignore_dicts=True
    )

def json_loads_byteified(json_text):
    return _byteify(
        json.loads(json_text, object_hook=_byteify),
        ignore_dicts=True
    )

def _byteify(data, ignore_dicts = False):
    if isinstance(data, str):
        return data

    # If this is a list of values, return list of byteified values
    if isinstance(data, list):
        return [ _byteify(item, ignore_dicts=True) for item in data ]
    # If this is a dictionary, return dictionary of byteified keys and values
    # but only if we haven't already byteified it
    if isinstance(data, dict) and not ignore_dicts:
        return {
            _byteify(key, ignore_dicts=True): _byteify(value, ignore_dicts=True)
            for key, value in data.items() # changed to .items() for Python 2.7/3
        }

    # Python 3 compatible duck-typing
    # If this is a Unicode string, return its string representation
    if str(type(data)) == "<type 'unicode'>":
        return data.encode('utf-8')

    # If it's anything else, return it in its original form
    return data
```

Example usage:

```
>>> json_loads_byteified('{"Hello": "World"}')
{'Hello': 'World'}
>>> json_loads_byteified('"I am a top-level string"')
'I am a top-level string'
>>> json_loads_byteified('7')
7
>>> json_loads_byteified('["I am inside a list"]')
['I am inside a list']
>>> json_loads_byteified('[[[[[[[["I am inside a big nest of lists"]]]]]]]]')
[[[[[[[['I am inside a big nest of lists']]]]]]]]
>>> json_loads_byteified('{"foo": "bar", "things": [7, {"qux": "baz", "moo": {"cow": ["milk"]}}]}')
{'things': [7, {'qux': 'baz', 'moo': {'cow': ['milk']}}], 'foo': 'bar'}
>>> json_load_byteified(open('somefile.json'))
{'more json': 'from a file'}
```

#### How does this work and why would I use it?

[Mark Amery's function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13105359/1709587) is shorter and clearer than these ones, so what's the point of them? Why would you want to use them?

Purely for **performance**. Mark's answer decodes the JSON text fully first with Unicode strings, then recurses through the entire decoded value to convert all strings to byte strings. This has a couple of undesirable effects:

- A copy of the entire decoded structure gets created in memory
- If your JSON object is *really* deeply nested (500 levels or more) then you'll hit Python's maximum recursion depth

This answer mitigates both of those performance issues by using the `object_hook` parameter of `json.load` and `json.loads`. From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load):

> `object_hook` is an optional function that will be called with the result of any object literal decoded (a `dict`). The return value of object_hook will be used instead of the `dict`. This feature can be used to implement custom decoders

Since dictionaries nested many levels deep in other dictionaries get passed to `object_hook` *as they're decoded*, we can byteify any strings or lists inside them at that point and avoid the need for deep recursion later.

Mark's answer isn't suitable for use as an `object_hook` as it stands, because it recurses into nested dictionaries. We prevent that recursion in this answer with the `ignore_dicts` parameter to `_byteify`, which gets passed to it at all times *except* when `object_hook` passes it a new `dict` to byteify. The `ignore_dicts` flag tells `_byteify` to ignore `dict`s since they already been byteified.

Finally, our implementations of `json_load_byteified` and `json_loads_byteified` call `_byteify` (with `ignore_dicts=True`) on the result returned from `json.load` or `json.loads` to handle the case where the JSON text being decoded doesn't have a `dict` at the top level.

Comment: +1 for the approach here; I didn't really grasp it when I first read it, but finally understood when rereading it in light of Travis Jensen's answer. I've made a pretty aggressive edit in the hopes of clarifying how it works and what its advantages over my answer are. The core idea of the code remains untouched, but I've modified pretty much everything else. Feel free to roll back my edit if you object to this - it's your answer!

Comment: No problem Mark, many thanks. I like your edit, it is much more explanatory than my original. Maybe, one day, I'll learn to give more concise answers.

Comment: This is great solution; efficient and elegant. However, if you're stuck in the realm of Python < 2.7, as I am, you will need to replace the line: `return { byteify(key, ignore_dicts=True): _byteify(value, ignore_dicts=True) for key, value in data.iteritems() }` with `return dict((_byteify(key, ignore_dicts=True), _byteify(value, ignore_dicts=True)) for key, value in data.iteritems())` for it to work.

Comment: I think you're wrong about the recursion depth issue. With yours, I can go up to 990: `json_loads_byteified('[' * 990 + ']' * 990)`. With 991 it crashes. Mark's still works with 991: `byteify(json.loads('[' * 991 + ']' * 991))`. It crashes at 992. So at least in this test, Mark's can go deeper, contrary to what you said.

Comment: @MarkAmery What do you think about my above comment? (I just saw in the edit history that it was actually you who added that claim).

Comment: @StefanPochmann Hmm. I don't perfectly recall what I tested 16 months ago, but something that immediately jumps out to me is that you're testing deeply-nested lists/arrays rather then deeply-nested dicts/objects. `object_hook` only gets invoked on each dict/object, not on each list/array so it's unsurprising that your *particular* test doesn't show the avoidance of the recursion limit that my edit described. Retry with deeply-nested dicts/objects instead, and I expect you'll see a different result!

Comment: @MarkAmery Ah, yes, with `'{"a": ' * n + '1' + '}' * n` yours can only go up to n=496. Mirec's isn't safe, either, but works up to n=984. Yours however works up to 990 if I replace its dictionary comprehension with a for loop that builds a dictionary. For some reason, dictionary comprehensions are turned into functions, doubling the recursion depth.

Comment: your code already generic , remove ignore_dict and it will work. One need not to worry about ignore_dict , it is already taken carelike 

 def _byteify(data):
  
    if isinstance(data, unicode):
        return data.encode('utf-8')
 
    if isinstance(data, list):
        return [ _byteify(item) for item in data ]
  

    if isinstance(data, dict):
        return {
            _byteify(key): _byteify(value)
            for key, value in data.iteritems()
        }
 
    return data

Comment: @RichardDunn unfortunately the world has shifted the other way, and now you'll have to be content with being incompatible with `data.items()` instead, since that is the python 2.7 and 3.x compatible method

Answer (score 188):

While there are some good answers here, I ended up using [PyYAML](http://pyyaml.org/) to parse my JSON files, since it gives the keys and values as `str` type strings instead of the `unicode` type. Because JSON is a subset of [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML), it works nicely:

```
>>> import json
>>> import yaml
>>> list_org = ['a', 'b']
>>> list_dump = json.dumps(list_org)
>>> list_dump
'["a", "b"]'
>>> json.loads(list_dump)
[u'a', u'b']
>>> yaml.safe_load(list_dump)
['a', 'b']
```

#### Notes

Some things to note though:

- I get *string objects* because all my entries are **ASCII encoded**. If I would use Unicode encoded entries, I would get them back as *unicode objects* — there is no conversion!
- You should (probably always) use PyYAML's `safe_load` function; if you use it to load JSON files, you don't need the "additional power" of the `load` function anyway.
- If you want a YAML parser that has more support for the 1.2 version of the spec (and [correctly parses very low numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458977/yaml-loads-5e-6-as-string-and-not-a-number)) try [Ruamel YAML](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml): `pip install ruamel.yaml` and `import ruamel.yaml as yaml` was all I needed in my tests.

#### Conversion

As stated, there isn't any conversion! If you can't be sure to only deal with ASCII values (and you can't be sure most of the time), better use a **conversion function**:

I used the one [from Mark Amery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956867/how-to-get-string-objects-instead-of-unicode-ones-from-json-in-python/13105359#13105359) a couple of times now, it works great and is very easy to use. You can also use a similar function as an `object_hook` instead, as it might gain you a performance boost on big files. See the slightly more involved [answer from Mirec Miskuf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33571117/11666) for that.

Comment: Take a little care if you decide to use this answer. It works perfectly for Brutus's case, but only because he knows that his data only contains ASCII-encodable characters. If you don't have that guarantee, this answer won't work. For example, try executing `yaml.load(json.dumps([u'a', u'£', u'É']))` at the Python shell and observe that you get back `['a', u'\xa3', u'\xc9']` (which contains `unicode` strings). If you can't be sure that your data only contains characters from the ASCII character set, you should use a different approach instead (I recommend my own answer).

Comment: YAML also makes use of `[u'a', u'b']` be careful.

Comment: This is nice, but it does not work with low numbers.. look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458977/yaml-loads-5e-6-as-string-and-not-a-number

Comment: @Oren: This is not an error in the [YAML spec](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2804092) but in the PyYAML parser. The [YAML parser from ruamel](https://bitbucket.org/ruamel/yaml) works.

Comment: I want to have ouput like ["a", "b"] not like ['a', 'b'] @Brutus

Comment: Awesome and easiest solution, Must be selected answer!
You will need pyyaml if you are using pip. Use sudo pip install pyyaml or in ubuntu sudo apt-get install pythom-yaml

Comment: I've found YAML is quite slow so you may not want to do this if performance is important.
See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27743711/can-i-speedup-yaml

Answer (score 146):

There's no built-in option to make the *json* module functions return byte strings instead of Unicode strings. However, this short and simple recursive function will convert any decoded JSON object from using Unicode strings to UTF-8-encoded byte strings:

```
def byteify(input):
    if isinstance(input, dict):
        return {byteify(key): byteify(value)
                for key, value in input.iteritems()}
    elif isinstance(input, list):
        return [byteify(element) for element in input]
    elif isinstance(input, unicode):
        return input.encode('utf-8')
    else:
        return input
```

Just call this on the output you get from a `json.load` or `json.loads` call.

A couple of notes:

- To support Python 2.6 or earlier, replace `return {byteify(key): byteify(value) for key, value in input.iteritems()}` with `return dict([(byteify(key), byteify(value)) for key, value in input.iteritems()])`, since dictionary comprehensions weren't supported until Python 2.7.
- Since this answer recurses through the entire decoded object, it has a couple of undesirable performance characteristics that can be avoided with very careful use of the `object_hook` or `object_pairs_hook` parameters. [Mirec Miskuf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33571117/1709587) is so far the only one that manages to pull this off correctly, although as a consequence, it's significantly more complicated than my approach.

Comment: I like this - it is not an ignore - it is recognizing that when people say "strings" and "ascii" they mostly naively meant they wanted bytes, not theoretical unicode characters. (and not ascii as they still want pound signs at the other end)

Comment: I like this, it works almost the same way as my pretty printer works, since I know that json don't make tuple, you should add the exception for tuple too.

Comment: This is horribly inefficient, requiring you to recursively traverse nodes that you may not need to. The json module gives you hooks to do this much more efficiently. The answer below using `object_hook` is actually far worse than this one, though, but, using `object_pairs_hook`, you can come up with a [reasonably efficient method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34796078/62660) that requires no recursion or revisiting of nodes that do not contain strings.

Comment: @TravisJensen Interesting. The `object_pairs_hook` method is perhaps very slightly harder to understand than this one (you need to understand how the parameter works and why lists and dicts require different handling), and the performance benefit won't matter to most people... but I'd expect it to exist, especially for anybody dealing with an unusually deeply nested JSON object.

Comment: plus1 This is the most concise answer; besides PyYAML is a pain to install. The only thing better would be to somehow micro-stream the conversion so it doesn't use 4X memory.

Answer (score 76):

You can use the `object_hook` parameter for [`json.loads`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.loads) to pass in a converter. You don't have to do the conversion after the fact. The [`json`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html) module will always pass the `object_hook` dicts only, and it will recursively pass in nested dicts, so you don't have to recurse into nested dicts yourself. I don't think I would convert Unicode strings to numbers like [Wells shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956867/how-to-get-string-objects-instead-of-unicode-from-json/1641528#1641528). If it's a Unicode string, it was quoted as a string in the JSON file, so it is supposed to be a string (or the file is bad).

Also, I'd try to avoid doing something like `str(val)` on a `unicode` object. You should use `value.encode(encoding)` with a valid encoding, depending on what your external library expects.

So, for example:

```
def _decode_list(data):
    rv = []
    for item in data:
        if isinstance(item, unicode):
            item = item.encode('utf-8')
        elif isinstance(item, list):
            item = _decode_list(item)
        elif isinstance(item, dict):
            item = _decode_dict(item)
        rv.append(item)
    return rv

def _decode_dict(data):
    rv = {}
    for key, value in data.iteritems():
        if isinstance(key, unicode):
            key = key.encode('utf-8')
        if isinstance(value, unicode):
            value = value.encode('utf-8')
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            value = _decode_list(value)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            value = _decode_dict(value)
        rv[key] = value
    return rv

obj = json.loads(s, object_hook=_decode_dict)
```

Comment: This is fine if the object in `s` is a JSON `Object` (an unordered collection of key:value pairs with the ':' character separating the key and the value, comma-separated and enclosed in curly braces), but not if it's, say, a JSON `Array`. So if given a JSON `Array` like `["a", "b"]`, the result will still be `[u'a', u'b']`. None of the other currently available customizing hook-type parameters for `json.loads()` can do the job either.

Comment: Since, as you mentioned, the `json` module will recursively pass in nested `dict`s, it's unnecessary to check for them in the two functions -- so the two `elif` clauses that check for them should be removed.

Comment: Note that starting function names with an underscore has a special meaning for import statements. If you put these functions in a file called Utility.py and in another file do `from Utility import *`, the functions will *not* be seen because of that underscore.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. `object_hook` gets called for every json object parsed, so if you recurse into what is given you, you are re-"byteifying" things that you have already "byteified". Performance is going to grow geometrically with the size of the object.

I've included an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34796078/62660) that uses `object_pairs_hook` and doesn't suffer from that problem.

Answer (score 39):

That's because *json()* has no difference between string objects and Unicode objects. They're all strings in JavaScript.

I think **JSON is right to return Unicode objects**. In fact, I wouldn't accept anything less, since JavaScript strings **are in fact `unicode` objects** (i.e., JSON (JavaScript) strings can store *any kind* of Unicode character), so it makes sense to create `unicode` objects when translating strings from JSON. Plain strings just wouldn't fit since the library would have to guess the encoding you want.

It's better to use `unicode` string objects everywhere. So your best option is to update your libraries so they can deal with Unicode objects.

But if you really want bytestrings, just encode the results to the encoding of your choice:

```
>>> nl = json.loads(js)
>>> nl
[u'a', u'b']
>>> nl = [s.encode('utf-8') for s in nl]
>>> nl
['a', 'b']
```

Comment: Thanks nosklo, that is what I have done first. But as I said, the real data I used is pretty nested and all, so this introduced quiety some overhead. 
I'm still looking for an automatic solution... There's at least one bug report out there where people complain about simplejson returning string objects instead of unicode.

Comment: @Brutus: I think json is right to return unicode objects. In fact, I wouldn't accept anything less, since javascript strings are in fact unicode objects. What I mean is that json (javascript) strings can store any kind of unicode character, so it makes sense to create unicode objects when translating from json. You should really fix your libraries instead.

Comment: Unless you have a python library, which passes to a C lib under the hood and it expects an as ASCII string.  I have that situation, and the bound C lib is raising `argument of type 'std::string const &'`.

Answer (score 16):

There exists an easy work-around.

TL;DR - Use `ast.literal_eval()` instead of `json.loads()`.  Both `ast` and `json` are in the standard library.

While not a 'perfect' answer, it gets one pretty far if your plan is to ignore Unicode altogether.  In Python 2.7

```
import json, ast
d = { 'field' : 'value' }
print "JSON Fail: ", json.loads(json.dumps(d))
print "AST Win:", ast.literal_eval(json.dumps(d))
```

gives:

```
JSON Fail:  {u'field': u'value'}
AST Win: {'field': 'value'}
```

This gets more hairy when some objects are really Unicode strings.  The full answer gets hairy quickly.

Comment: Better be sure your json doesn't contain any `null`, `true`, or `false` values, because they aren't valid in python and will cause `literal_eval()` to fail.

Comment: @ʇsәɹoɈ Also better hope your JSON doesn't contain an escaped solidus (`\/`) inside a string, or a unicode escape sequence (like `"\u0061"`, which is another way of writing `"a"`). Python's literal syntax is incompatible with JSON in several ways, and I wouldn't trust this answer for any script that I wasn't going to throw away.

Comment: People are right that if the string really is unicode then this answer fails, but if that were the case we wouldn't be able to cast to a string anyways. +1 for an answer that works only when it works and throws an exception otherwise

Comment: if possible don't use `json` to dump the data, just use `print` if running python. Then `ast.literal_eval` works

Answer (score 13):

[Mike Brennan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6633651/1517753) is close, but there isn't any reason to retraverse the entire structure. If you use the [`object_hook_pairs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load) (Python 2.7+) parameter:

> *`object_pairs_hook`* is an optional function that will be called with the result of any object literal decoded with an ordered list of pairs.  The return value of *`object_pairs_hook`* will be used instead of the `dict`. This feature can be used to implement custom decoders that rely on the order that the key and value pairs are decoded (for example, `collections.OrderedDict` will remember the order of insertion). If *`object_hook`* is also defined, the *`object_pairs_hook`* takes priority.

With it, you get each JSON object handed to you, so you can do the decoding with no need for recursion:

```
def deunicodify_hook(pairs):
    new_pairs = []
    for key, value in pairs:
        if isinstance(value, unicode):
            value = value.encode('utf-8')
        if isinstance(key, unicode):
            key = key.encode('utf-8')
        new_pairs.append((key, value))
    return dict(new_pairs)

In [52]: open('test.json').read()
Out[52]: '{"1": "hello", "abc": [1, 2, 3], "def": {"hi": "mom"}, "boo": [1, "hi", "moo", {"5": "some"}]}'

In [53]: json.load(open('test.json'))
Out[53]:
{u'1': u'hello',
 u'abc': [1, 2, 3],
 u'boo': [1, u'hi', u'moo', {u'5': u'some'}],
 u'def': {u'hi': u'mom'}}

In [54]: json.load(open('test.json'), object_pairs_hook=deunicodify_hook)
Out[54]:
{'1': 'hello',
 'abc': [1, 2, 3],
 'boo': [1, 'hi', 'moo', {'5': 'some'}],
 'def': {'hi': 'mom'}}
```

Notice that I never have to call the hook recursively since every object will get handed to the hook when you use the `object_pairs_hook`. You do have to care about lists, but as you can see, an object within a list will be properly converted, and you don't have to recurse to make it happen.

A coworker pointed out that Python2.6 doesn't have `object_hook_pairs`. You can still use this will Python2.6 by making a very small change. In the hook above, change:

```
for key, value in pairs:
```

to

```
for key, value in pairs.iteritems():
```

Then use `object_hook` instead of `object_pairs_hook`:

```
In [66]: json.load(open('test.json'), object_hook=deunicodify_hook)
Out[66]:
{'1': 'hello',
 'abc': [1, 2, 3],
 'boo': [1, 'hi', 'moo', {'5': 'some'}],
 'def': {'hi': 'mom'}}
```

Using `object_pairs_hook` results in one less dictionary being instantiated for each object in the JSON object, which, if you were parsing a huge document, might be worth while.

Comment: This is neat and seems very close to deserving the green checkmark (which Brutus has, admirably, already passed around liberally as better answers have come in). But... why not actually handle lists properly in the `deunicodify_hook` that you exhibit in this answer? At the moment, you have an implementation of `deunicodify_hook` that doesn't iterate over lists and deunicodify the strings and lists within them, and thus the output you're exhibiting does *not* match the output your hook will actually produce. Fix that, and this answer will be superior to mine.

Comment: Frivolous: I'd also suggest demonstrating the function with the ordinary CPython interpreter rather than the one you're using here (which I think is IronPython)? The CPython interpreter is more familiar to most Python users and is, in my opinion, prettier.

Comment: This doesn't work for me but I'm sure it's some quirk of what I'm doing ... I'm storing one list from a larger json doc to a file. Whether I load it with or without this object_pairs_hook, every item comes up unicode. Darn.

Comment: @rsaw Good point! Since the `object_pairs_hook` only gets called for *objects*, if your JSON text has a list of strings at the top level, this solution will fail. There's no way to fix this without calling some function on the thing returned from `json.load`; none of the `json.load` hooks can guarantee you'll be able to deal with every string. I think this is a big enough flaw for me to keep recommending my solution over using the hooks.

Comment: -1 because I just realised that Mirec Miskuf [already posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33571117/1709587) an object-hook answer that neither has the disadvantages of Mike Brennan's approach (re-byteifies the same dictionaries multiple times) nor of this one (fails to byteify nested lists or top-level lists or strings). I'm not sure why his answer has languished with almost no attention while this one - which is inferior - has rapidly gained votes.

Answer (score 9):

I'm afraid there isn't any way to achieve this automatically within the *simplejson* library.

The scanner and decoder in *simplejson* are designed to produce Unicode text. To do this, the library uses a function called `c_scanstring` (if it's available, for speed), or `py_scanstring` if the C version is not available. The `scanstring` function is called several times by nearly every routine that *simplejson* has for decoding a structure that might contain text. You'd have to either [monkey patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) the `scanstring` value in *simplejson.decoder*, or subclass `JSONDecoder` and provide pretty much your own entire implementation of anything that might contain text.

The reason that *simplejson* outputs Unicode, however, is that the [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/) specifically mentions that "A string is a collection of zero or more Unicode characters"... support for Unicode is assumed as part of the format itself. *simplejson*'s `scanstring` implementation goes so far as to scan and interpret Inicode escapes (even error-checking for malformed multi-byte charset representations), so the only way it can reliably return the value to you is as Unicode.

If you have an aged library that needs an `str`, I recommend you either laboriously search the nested data structure after parsing (which I acknowledge is what you explicitly said you wanted to avoid... sorry), or perhaps wrap your libraries in some sort of [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) where you can massage the input parameters at a more granular level. The second approach might be more manageable than the first if your data structures are indeed deeply nested.

Answer (score 4):

As [Mark (Amery) correctly notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956867/how-to-get-string-objects-instead-of-unicode-from-json/13105359#13105359): Using [PyYAML](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML)'s deserializer on a JSON dump works only if you have ASCII only. At least out of the box.

Two quick comments on the PyYAML approach:

1. ***[Never](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjZHjvrAS74)*** use *yaml.load()* on data from the field. It’s a feature(!) of YAML to execute arbitrary code hidden within the structure.
2. You *can* make it work also for non ASCII via this:

   ```
    def to_utf8(loader, node):
        return loader.construct_scalar(node).encode('utf-8')
    yaml.add_constructor(u'tag:yaml.org,2002:str', to_utf8)
   ```

But performance-wise, it’s of no comparison to Mark Amery's answer:

Throwing some deeply-nested sample dicts onto the two methods, I get this (with dt[j] = time delta of json.loads(json.dumps(m))):

```
     dt[yaml.safe_load(json.dumps(m))] =~ 100 * dt[j]
     dt[byteify recursion(Mark Amery)] =~   5 * dt[j]
```

So deserialization, including fully walking the tree *and* encoding, is well within the order of magnitude of JSON's C-based implementation. I find this remarkably fast and its also more robust than the *yaml* load at deeply nested structures. And less security error prone, looking at yaml.load.

=> While I would appreciate a pointer to a C-only based converter, the **byteify function** should be the default answer.

This holds especially true if your JSON structure is from the field, containing user input. Because then you probably need to walk *anyway* over your structure - independent on your desired internal data structures ('unicode sandwich' or byte strings only).

Why?

Unicode **normalisation**. For the unaware: Take a painkiller and read [this](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/counting-characters).

So using the byteify recursion you kill two birds with one stone:

1. get your bytestrings from nested JSON dumps
2. get user input values normalised, so that you find the stuff in your storage.

In my tests it turned out that replacing the input.encode('utf-8') with a *unicodedata.normalize('NFC', input).encode('utf-8')* was even faster than without NFC - but that’s heavily dependent on the sample data I guess.

Answer (score 3):

The gotcha is that `simplejson` and `json` are two different modules, at least in the manner they deal with Unicode. You have `json` in Python 2.6+, and this gives you Unicode values, whereas `simplejson` returns string objects.

Just try easy_install-ing *simplejson* in your environment and see if that works. It did for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) instead of *json* for dump and load, like so:

```
    import json
    import pickle

    d = { 'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 2, }

    json.dump(d,open("testjson.txt","w"))

    print json.load(open("testjson.txt","r"))

    pickle.dump(d,open("testpickle.txt","w"))

    print pickle.load(open("testpickle.txt","r"))
```

The output it produces is (strings and integers are handled correctly):

```
    {u'field2': 2, u'field1': u'value1'}
    {'field2': 2, 'field1': 'value1'}
```

Comment: +1 for a solution that doesn't require additional packages (like *yaml*). But sometimes - like in my original case - I need to have the data in JSON, so *pickle* is not always the best option. Besides, you have `safe_load` in YAML, I don't know if something similar exist for *pickle*.

Answer (score 2):

I had a JSON dict as a string. The keys and values were Unicode objects like in the following example:

```
myStringDict = "{u'key':u'value'}"
```

I could use the `byteify` function suggested above by converting the string to a `dict` object using `ast.literal_eval(myStringDict)`.

Comment: The example you have given is not an example of JSON. `{u'key':u'value'}` is not JSON.

Comment: I perfectly know it is not JSON. That's how it was parsed from an external source in my python script. If it was JSON directly like in the following example, I wouldn't need the byteify function marked as the solution:
{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}. It would be just great if before voting you read the answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, I've run into the same problem.

Because I need to pass all data to [PyGTK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyGTK), Unicode strings aren't very useful to me either. So I have another recursive conversion method. It's actually also needed for type-safe JSON conversion - json.dump() would bail on any non-literals, like Python objects. It doesn't convert dict indexes though.

```
# removes any objects, turns Unicode back into str
def filter_data(obj):
        if type(obj) in (int, float, str, bool):
                return obj
        elif type(obj) == unicode:
                return str(obj)
        elif type(obj) in (list, tuple, set):
                obj = list(obj)
                for i,v in enumerate(obj):
                        obj[i] = filter_data(v)
        elif type(obj) == dict:
                for i,v in obj.iteritems():
                        obj[i] = filter_data(v)
        else:
                print "invalid object in data, converting to string"
                obj = str(obj)
        return obj
```

Comment: The only problem that might come up here is if you need the keys in a dictionary converted from unicode. Though this implementation will convert the values, it maintains the unicode keys.  If you create a 'newobj', use newobj[str(i)] = ..., and assign obj = newobj when you're done, the keys will be converted as well.

Comment: This could be prettier with comprehensions or better by converting keys. It's also unidiomatic; it both mutates objects in place (in the case of dictionaries) and returns the new value, which is inconsistent with Python's built-in collection methods which either mutate the current object or return a new one, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

Support for Python 2 and 3 using a hook (from [Mirec Miskuf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956867/how-to-get-string-objects-instead-of-unicode-from-json/33571117#33571117)):

```
import requests
import six
from six import iteritems

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()  # @UndefinedVariable
r = requests.get("http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two/three", verify=False)

def _byteify(data):
    # If this is a Unicode string, return its string representation
    if isinstance(data, six.string_types):
        return str(data.encode('utf-8').decode())

    # If this is a list of values, return list of byteified values
    if isinstance(data, list):
        return [ _byteify(item) for item in data ]

    # If this is a dictionary, return dictionary of byteified keys and values,
    # but only if we haven't already byteified it
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        return {
            _byteify(key): _byteify(value) for key, value in iteritems(data)
        }
    # If it's anything else, return it in its original form
    return data

w = r.json(object_hook=_byteify)
print(w)
```

Returns:

```
 {'three': '', 'key': 'value', 'one': 'two'}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Python 3.6, sometimes I still run into this problem. For example, when getting a response from a [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API and loading the response text to JSON, I still get the Unicode strings.
Found a simple solution using json.dumps().

```
response_message = json.loads(json.dumps(response.text))
print(response_message)
```

Answer (score 0):

I built this recursive caster. It works for my needs and I think it's relatively complete.

```
def _parseJSON(self, obj):
    newobj = {}

    for key, value in obj.iteritems():
        key = str(key)

        if isinstance(value, dict):
            newobj[key] = self._parseJSON(value)
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            if key not in newobj:
                newobj[key] = []
                for i in value:
                    newobj[key].append(self._parseJSON(i))
        elif isinstance(value, unicode):
            val = str(value)
            if val.isdigit():
                val = int(val)
            else:
                try:
                    val = float(val)
                except ValueError:
                    val = str(val)
            newobj[key] = val

    return newobj
```

Just pass it a JSON object like so:

```
obj = json.loads(content, parse_float=float, parse_int=int)
obj = _parseJSON(obj)
```

I have it as a private member of a class, but you can repurpose the method as you see fit.

Comment: I've run into a problem where I'm trying to parse JSON and pass the resulting mapping to a function as **kwargs.  It looks like function parameter names cannot be unicode, so your _parseJSON function is great.  If there's an easier way, someone can let me know.

Comment: This code has a problem - you make a recursive call in the List piece, which is going to fail if the elements of the list are not themselves dictionaries.

Comment: Besides the bug described by @I82Much, this is also badly named (it doesn't actually parse the JSON; a `json.loads` call is needed first), arbitrarily tries to convert strings to ints for no explained reason, and isn't copy-and-paste ready.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote [Wells's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956867/how-to-get-string-objects-instead-of-unicode-from-json/1641528#1641528) *_parse_json()* to handle cases where the *json* object itself is an array (my use case).

```
def _parseJSON(self, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        newobj = {}
        for key, value in obj.iteritems():
            key = str(key)
            newobj[key] = self._parseJSON(value)
    elif isinstance(obj, list):
        newobj = []
        for value in obj:
            newobj.append(self._parseJSON(value))
    elif isinstance(obj, unicode):
        newobj = str(obj)
    else:
        newobj = obj
    return newobj
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive encoder written in C:
https://github.com/axiros/nested_encode

The performance overhead for "average" structures is around 10% compared to *json.loads()*.

```
python speed.py
  json loads            [0.16sec]: {u'a': [{u'b': [[1, 2, [u'\xd6ster..
  json loads + encoding [0.18sec]: {'a': [{'b': [[1, 2, ['\xc3\x96ster.
  time overhead in percent: 9%
```

using this teststructure:

```
import json, nested_encode, time

s = """
{
  "firstName": "Jos\\u0301",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "isAlive": true,
  "age": 25,
  "address": {
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city": "\\u00d6sterreich",
    "state": "NY",
    "postalCode": "10021-3100"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "office",
      "number": "646 555-4567"
    }
  ],
  "children": [],
  "spouse": null,
  "a": [{"b": [[1, 2, ["\\u00d6sterreich"]]]}]
}
"""


t1 = time.time()
for i in xrange(10000):
    u = json.loads(s)
dt_json = time.time() - t1

t1 = time.time()
for i in xrange(10000):
    b = nested_encode.encode_nested(json.loads(s))
dt_json_enc = time.time() - t1

print "json loads            [%.2fsec]: %s..." % (dt_json, str(u)[:20])
print "json loads + encoding [%.2fsec]: %s..." % (dt_json_enc, str(b)[:20])

print "time overhead in percent: %i%%"  % (100 * (dt_json_enc - dt_json)/dt_json)
```

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem too, and having to deal with JSON, I came up with a small loop that converts the Unicode keys to strings.  (`simplejson` on [GAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine) does not return string keys.)

`obj` is the object decoded from JSON:

```py
if NAME_CLASS_MAP.has_key(cls):
    kwargs = {}
    for i in obj.keys():
        kwargs[str(i)] = obj[i]
    o = NAME_CLASS_MAP[cls](**kwargs)
    o.save()
```

`kwargs` is what I pass to the constructor of the GAE application (which does not like Unicode keys in `**kwargs`).

It is not as robust as [the solution from Wells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956867/how-to-get-string-objects-instead-of-unicode-from-json/1641528#1641528), but much smaller.

Answer (score -1):

I've adapted the code from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13105359/611007) of [Mark Amery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1709587/mark-amery), particularly in order to get rid of `isinstance` for the pros of [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

The encoding is done manually and `ensure_ascii` is disabled. The Python documentation for [`json.dump`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dump) says that:

> If ensure_ascii is True (the default), all non-ASCII characters in the output are escaped with \uXXXX sequences

Disclaimer: in the doctest I used the Hungarian language. Some notable Hungarian-related character encodings are: `cp852`, the IBM/OEM encoding used e.g. in [DOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS) (sometimes referred to as *ASCII*. Incorrectly I think, as it is dependent on the *[code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page)* setting). [Windows-1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) is used e.g. in Windows (sometimes referred as ANSI, dependent on the locale settings), and [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), sometimes used on HTTP servers.

The test text `Tüskéshátú kígyóbűvölő` is attributed to *Koltai László* (native personal name form) and is [from Wikipedia](https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%81rv%C3%ADzt%C5%B1r%C5%91_t%C3%BCk%C3%B6rf%C3%BAr%C3%B3g%C3%A9p#Egy.C3.A9b_magyar_tesztsz.C3.B6vegek).

```
# coding: utf-8
"""
This file should be encoded correctly with utf-8.
"""
import json

def encode_items(input, encoding='utf-8'):
    u"""original from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13101776/611007
    adapted by SO/u/611007 (20150623)
    >>>
    >>> ## run this with `python -m doctest <this file>.py` from command line
    >>>
    >>> txt = u"Tüskéshátú kígyóbűvölő"
    >>> txt2 = u"T\\u00fcsk\\u00e9sh\\u00e1t\\u00fa k\\u00edgy\\u00f3b\\u0171v\\u00f6l\\u0151"
    >>> txt3 = u"uúuutifu"
    >>> txt4 = b'u\\xfauutifu'
    >>> # txt4 shouldn't be 'u\\xc3\\xbauutifu', string content needs double backslash for doctest:
    >>> assert u'\\u0102' not in b'u\\xfauutifu'.decode('cp1250')
    >>> txt4u = txt4.decode('cp1250')
    >>> assert txt4u == u'u\\xfauutifu', repr(txt4u)
    >>> txt5 = b"u\\xc3\\xbauutifu"
    >>> txt5u = txt5.decode('utf-8')
    >>> txt6 = u"u\\u251c\\u2551uutifu"
    >>> there_and_back_again = lambda t: encode_items(t, encoding='utf-8').decode('utf-8')
    >>> assert txt == there_and_back_again(txt)
    >>> assert txt == there_and_back_again(txt2)
    >>> assert txt3 == there_and_back_again(txt3)
    >>> assert txt3.encode('cp852') == there_and_back_again(txt4u).encode('cp852')
    >>> assert txt3 == txt4u,(txt3,txt4u)
    >>> assert txt3 == there_and_back_again(txt5)
    >>> assert txt3 == there_and_back_again(txt5u)
    >>> assert txt3 == there_and_back_again(txt4u)
    >>> assert txt3.encode('cp1250') == encode_items(txt4, encoding='utf-8')
    >>> assert txt3.encode('utf-8') == encode_items(txt5, encoding='utf-8')
    >>> assert txt2.encode('utf-8') == encode_items(txt, encoding='utf-8')
    >>> assert {'a':txt2.encode('utf-8')} == encode_items({'a':txt}, encoding='utf-8')
    >>> assert [txt2.encode('utf-8')] == encode_items([txt], encoding='utf-8')
    >>> assert [[txt2.encode('utf-8')]] == encode_items([[txt]], encoding='utf-8')
    >>> assert [{'a':txt2.encode('utf-8')}] == encode_items([{'a':txt}], encoding='utf-8')
    >>> assert {'b':{'a':txt2.encode('utf-8')}} == encode_items({'b':{'a':txt}}, encoding='utf-8')
    """
    try:
        input.iteritems
        return {encode_items(k): encode_items(v) for (k,v) in input.iteritems()}
    except AttributeError:
        if isinstance(input, unicode):
            return input.encode(encoding)
        elif isinstance(input, str):
            return input
        try:
            iter(input)
            return [encode_items(e) for e in input]
        except TypeError:
            return input

def alt_dumps(obj, **kwargs):
    """
    >>> alt_dumps({'a': u"T\\u00fcsk\\u00e9sh\\u00e1t\\u00fa k\\u00edgy\\u00f3b\\u0171v\\u00f6l\\u0151"})
    '{"a": "T\\xc3\\xbcsk\\xc3\\xa9sh\\xc3\\xa1t\\xc3\\xba k\\xc3\\xadgy\\xc3\\xb3b\\xc5\\xb1v\\xc3\\xb6l\\xc5\\x91"}'
    """
    if 'ensure_ascii' in kwargs:
        del kwargs['ensure_ascii']
    return json.dumps(encode_items(obj), ensure_ascii=False, **kwargs)
```

I'd also like to highlight [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/957274/611007) of [Jarret Hardie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72247/jarret-hardie) which references the [JSON specification](https://www.json.org/), quoting:

> A string is a collection of zero or more Unicode characters

In my use case, I had files with JSON content. They are [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded files. `ensure_ascii` results in properly escaped, but not very readable JSON files, and that is why I've adapted Mark Amery's answer to fit my needs.

The doctest is not particularly thoughtful, but I share the code in the hope that it will useful for someone.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the benefits of using duck typing here? We know that collections returned from `json.loads` are going to be lists or dicts, not some user-defined or library-defined type that implements their methods and magic methods, so why not just do an `isinstance` check? Isn't that easier to understand than checking for the existence of `iteritems` or whether `iter` will accept the object as an argument?

Comment: @MarkAmery this is about dumps, not loads. if you *create* data to dump - as opposed to *loading* it - you cannot be sure what it is. the idea was to let it come from anywhere in the code.

Answer (score -2):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13940335/3405255) to a similar question like this which states that

The *u-* prefix just means that you have a Unicode string.  When you really use the string, it won't appear in your data.  Don't be thrown by the printed output.

For example, try this:

```
print mail_accounts[0]["i"]
```

You won't see a *u*.

Comment: Not true if e.g. you want to format something containing a unicode string, in Py2. e.g. `'{}'.format({u'x' : u'y'})` still includes the u's.