# Using Python simplejson for transmitting JSON to another server results in unicode encoding problems

Tags: python, json, unicode, simplejson

I'm encoding a string with Python's simplejson library with special characters:

> hello testing
>
> spécißl characters
>
> plusses: +++++
>
> special chars :œ∑´®†¥¨ˆøπ“ß∂ƒ©˙∆˚¬Ω≈ç√∫˜µ≤≥

However, when I encode it and transmit it to the other machine (using POST), it turns out like this:

> {'message': ['{"body": "hello testing sp\\u00e9ci\\u00dfl characters\\n\\nplusses:      \\n\\nspecial chars :\\u0153\\u2211\\u00b4\\u00ae\\u2020\\u00a5\\u00a8\\u02c6\\u00f8\\u03c0\\u201c\\u00df\\u2202\\u0192\\u00a9\\u02d9\\u2206\\u02da\\u00ac\\u03a9\\u2248\\u00e7\\u221a\\u222b\\u02dc\\u00b5\\u2264\\u2265"}']}

The + signs are completely stripped and the rest are in this unicode(?) format. My code for this is:

```
data = {'body': data_string}
data_encoded = json.dumps(data)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: I've tried using `json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)` but it results in a `UnicodeError ordinal not in range` error.

Comment: well, the +s are missing, and I'm trying to figure out how to convert the unicode character representations back to normal. and .encode('utf-8') doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I'm thinking there's a fundamental thing that's going wrong, so that's why I'm asking :)

Comment: Just as a hint, there's a difference between `json` and `simplejson` in the manner they deal with unicode. Check out this other question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956867/how-to-get-string-objects-instead-unicode-ones-from-json-in-python/3972139#3972139

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import json
```

simple example, with plusses, Latin1 "s sharp", Cyrillic "capital zhe"

Note: ensure that your strings are unicode or ASCII:

```
>>> data = {"body" : u"++\xdf\u0416", "universe": 42}
>>> data
{'body': u'++\xdf\u0416', 'universe': 42}
```

Create your JSON string, which turns out to be ASCII -- all non-ASCII characters are escaped:

```
>>> encoded = json.dumps(data)
>>> encoded
'{"body": "++\\u00df\\u0416", "universe": 42}'
```

Transmit your JSON string to another computer. *Make sure to do any further escaping necessary if your transmission channel mangles ASCII characters. On the remote computer, do any necessary unescaping to recover the JSON string.*

Then convert the JSON string back to a Python object:

```
>>> decoded = json.loads(encoded)
>>> decoded
{u'body': u'++\xdf\u0416', u'universe': 42}
>>> decoded == data
True
>>>
```

A note on `ensure_ascii=False`: this will produce a `unicode` string:

```
>>> u_encoded = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)
>>> u_encoded
u'{"body": "++\xdf\u0416", "universe": 42}'
```

which must be encoded (`UTF-8` is suggested) into a `str` string before you can transmit it, and decoded at the other end. You still need to take precautions against mangled `+ < > &` etc characters.

Answer (score 0):

you doing it like that?

```
>>> s = u"""
... hello testing
... 
... spécißl characters
... 
... plusses: +++++
... 
... special chars :œ∑´®†¥¨ˆøπ“ß∂ƒ©˙∆˚¬Ω≈ç√∫˜µ≤≥
... """
>>> from json import dumps, loads
>>> loads(dumps(s))
u'\nhello testing\n\nsp\xe9ci\xdfl characters\n\nplusses: +++++\n\nspecial chars :\u0153\u2211\xb4\xae\u2020\xa5\xa8\u02c6\xf8\u03c0\u201c\xdf\u2202\u0192\xa9\u02d9\u2206\u02da\xac\u03a9\u2248\xe7\u221a\u222b\u02dc\xb5\u2264\u2265\n'
>>> print loads(dumps(s))

hello testing

spécißl characters

plusses: +++++

special chars :œ∑´®†¥¨ˆøπ“ß∂ƒ©˙∆˚¬Ω≈ç√∫˜µ≤≥

>>>
```

Comment: not getting the same behavior here.. `logging.info(loads(dumps(data)))` => `u'hello testing sp\xe9ci\xdfl characters\n\nplusses: +++++\n\nspecial chars :\u0153\u2211\xb4\xae\u2020\xa5\xa8\u02c6\xf8\u03c0\u201c\xdf\u2202\u0192\xa9 \u02d9\u2206\u02da\xac\u03a9\u2248\xe7\u221a\u222b\u02dc\xb5\u2264\u2265'`

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: you sure it was unicode before?

>>> x = u'łąść'.encode('utf-8')
>>> x
'\xc5\x82\xc4\x85\xc5\x9b\xc4\x87'
>>> print x.decode('utf-8')
łąść
>>>