# How to decode JSON to str and not unicode in Python (2.6)?

Tags: python, json, unicode

I have a configuration file in JSON that contains a few variables as strings (always ascii). These strings are decoded to unicode by default but since I have to pass these variables to my Python C Extensions I need them as normal Python strings. At the moment I'm using `str(unicode)` to convert the JSON strings but a more elegant and less verbose solution would be much appreciated.

Is there a way to change the default translation from string to unicode with a custom `JSONDecoder` or object hook?

Comment: Yes, a custom JSONDecoder should be able to skip the decoding from str to Unicode and return the raw binary string.

Comment: @Lennart Regebro I tried to do that and failed: I had to copy-n-paste-extend a lot of classes and module private constants. Is there a simple way to just tweak JSONDecoder that I can't see?

Comment: @TryPyPy: There is no such thing as module private constants in Python...

Comment: OMG. I don't know what kind of brain rot got to me, but if you actually look at my code below (before I make it saner), I acted as if _var + __all__ were impenetrable. Wow, thanks for opening my eyes, I can't explain what happened here...

Comment: :-) I looked at the code, and I have to agree it's fairly hard to override though...

Comment: import json
foo = "{'bar': 'baz'}"
json.loads(foo, 'ascii')

Answer (score 1):

Not if you're not willing to lose some speed. If being somewhat slower is OK, you have to consider that using plain `json.loads` and recursively converting to `str` is probably cheaper and maybe faster.

With all that said, if you do want a `loads` that returns strings badly enough <strike>to accept going through extending code that wasn't meant to, here's one possible result (mostly extending through copy-n-paste)</strike> this was asinine, thanks Lennart for making me see the light (i.e., you just need to extend JSONDecoder and a couple of tricks):

```
import json
from json import decoder, scanner

from json.scanner import make_scanner
from _json import scanstring as c_scanstring

_CONSTANTS = json.decoder._CONSTANTS

py_make_scanner = scanner.py_make_scanner

# Convert from unicode to str
def str_scanstring(*args, **kwargs):
    result = c_scanstring(*args, **kwargs)
    return str(result[0]), result[1]

# Little dirty trick here
json.decoder.scanstring = str_scanstring

class StrJSONDecoder(decoder.JSONDecoder):
    def __init__(self, encoding=None, object_hook=None, parse_float=None,
            parse_int=None, parse_constant=None, strict=True,
            object_pairs_hook=None):
        self.encoding = encoding
        self.object_hook = object_hook
        self.object_pairs_hook = object_pairs_hook
        self.parse_float = parse_float or float
        self.parse_int = parse_int or int
        self.parse_constant = parse_constant or _CONSTANTS.__getitem__
        self.strict = strict
        self.parse_object = decoder.JSONObject
        self.parse_array = decoder.JSONArray
        self.parse_string = str_scanstring
        self.scan_once = py_make_scanner(self)

# And another little dirty trick there    
_default_decoder = StrJSONDecoder(encoding=None, object_hook=None,
                               object_pairs_hook=None)

json._default_decoder = _default_decoder

j = {1:'2', 1.1:[1,2,3], u'test': {12:12, 13:'o'}}
print json.loads(json.dumps(j))
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I realise now that what I wanted is not supported for a reason, so I will stick to the str(unicode) solution.

Comment: Sorry to have scared you, Lennart made me realize it's much easier to get what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

See if the responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/956867/183791) helps you (in that question the asker was using `simplejson`).