# CSV delimiter that is read from a file

Tags: python, csv, character-encoding

I have a json settings file that contains the settings for my script. Part of the settings is the delimiter for the `csv.writer()`.

When it is being read into the variable `settings` and printed it giving me this: `{'delimiter': u','}`

When I try use this in the `csv.writer(out, **settings)` I get the following error: `TypeError: "delimiter" must be an 1-character string`.

Now to fix this I do do this: `settings["delimiter"] = settings["delimiter"].encode("utf-8")`

...but I am wondering if there is a way I can read this file in the first place which would mean I didn't have do to this?

EDIT:

Settings file is read like this:

```
    with open(file) as settings:
        details = json.load(settings)
```

Comment: And how are you reading that settings file in the first place?

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4723535/155813 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the JSON standard uses unicode throughout (this is a good thing). The `json` library has no options, short of subclassing the decoder, to switch to returning byte strings instead.

Just encode the delimiter.