# Forcing Python json module to work with ASCII

Tags: json, unicode, ascii, python-2.x

I'm using json.dump() and json.load() to save/read a dictionary of strings to/from disk. The issue is that I can't have any of the strings in unicode. They seem to be in unicode no matter how I set the parameters to dump/load (including ensure_ascii and encoding).

Comment: Please post your actual code and any error messages you are getting. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by “in Unicode”? Are you talking about the escaping of non-ASCII characters to `\u1234` escapes? If so why is this encoding not acceptable? It's perfectly valid JSON which any parser must accept; there are characters which *must* be encoded in this format even if in general you are leaving non-ASCII characters unescaped.

Comment: Because JSON natively is utf-8 format. Python's json.loads() accepts non-ascii symbols and parses them into Unicode strings. jsob.loads() parses all strings into 'unicode' Python type, not 'str'.
But json.dumps() escapes **all** non-ascii symbols! So, string != json.dumps( json.loads( string ) )

Comment: Retagged because this question does not make sense in a 3.x context.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are just dealing with simple JSON objects, you can use the following:

```
def ascii_encode_dict(data):
    ascii_encode = lambda x: x.encode('ascii')
    return dict(map(ascii_encode, pair) for pair in data.items())

json.loads(json_data, object_hook=ascii_encode_dict)
```

Here is an example of how it works:

```
>>> json_data = '{"foo": "bar", "bar": "baz"}'
>>> json.loads(json_data)                                # old call gives unicode
{u'foo': u'bar', u'bar': u'baz'}
>>> json.loads(json_data, object_hook=ascii_encode_dict) # new call gives str
{'foo': 'bar', 'bar': 'baz'}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6633651/505154) works for a more complex JSON structure, and gives some nice explanation on the `object_hook` parameter.  There is also another answer there that recursively takes the result of a `json.loads()` call and converts all of the Unicode strings to byte strings.

Comment: You might want to change the line to `ascii_encode = lambda x: x.encode('ascii','ignore') if the data have many characters whose `ord > 128`.

Comment: The link to the other answer for the more complex JSON structure was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 15):

And if the json object is a mix of datatypes, not only unicode strings, you can use this expression:

```
def ascii_encode_dict(data):
    ascii_encode = lambda x: x.encode('ascii') if isinstance(x, unicode) else x 
    return dict(map(ascii_encode, pair) for pair in data.items())
```