# How to find a particular JSON value by key?

Tags: python, json, search

There is a JSON like this:

```
{
  "P1": "ss",
  "Id": 1234,
  "P2": {
      "P1": "cccc"
  },
  "P3": [
      {
          "P1": "aaa"
      }
  ]
}
```

How can I find all `P1`'s value without it iterating all JSON?

P.S.: `P1` can be *anywhere* in the JSON.

If no method can do this, can you tell me how to iterate through the JSON?

Comment: If it can be anywhere in the set of nested structures, then you're going to have to look through all of it. That's just how reality works.

Comment: Maybe this is what you need? https://www.p6r.com/articles/2008/05/06/xslt-and-xpath-for-json/

Comment: see my json2xml solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361224/python-json-load-returning-string-instead-of-dictionary/64575834#64575834

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My approach to this problem would be different.

As JSON doesn't allow depth first search, so convert the json to a Python Object, feed it to an XML decoder and then extract the Node you are intending to search

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
import json        
def bar(somejson, key):
    def val(node):
        # Searches for the next Element Node containing Value
        e = node.nextSibling
        while e and e.nodeType != e.ELEMENT_NODE:
            e = e.nextSibling
        return (e.getElementsByTagName('string')[0].firstChild.nodeValue if e 
                else None)
    # parse the JSON as XML
    foo_dom = parseString(xmlrpclib.dumps((json.loads(somejson),)))
    # and then search all the name tags which are P1's
    # and use the val user function to get the value
    return [val(node) for node in foo_dom.getElementsByTagName('name') 
            if node.firstChild.nodeValue in key]

bar(foo, 'P1')
[u'cccc', u'aaa', u'ss']
bar(foo, ('P1','P2'))
[u'cccc', u'cccc', u'aaa', u'ss']
```

Comment: What is `xmlrpclib`? I think python 3 doesn't support it. I am getting error.

Comment: @JafferWilson: The [Python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html) says "The `xmlrpclib` module has been renamed to `xmlrpc.client` in Python 3." The Python 3 documentation for it being [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xmlrpc.client.html).

Comment: unfortunately, it seems to be working only when the value is string or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @viveksinghggits: In python there is no json data type. You have to pass the json as string.

Comment: @Abhijit I agree but what I meant was `bar(foo, 'Id')` is resulting in an error, because the value for key `Id` is int.

Comment: @viveksinghggits: FWIW, the code in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14059645/355230) doesn't care what the type the key value is (nor require converting the JSON to XML).

Answer (score 34):

As I said in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14055129/355230), I don't think there is a way of finding all values associated with the `"P1"` key without iterating over the whole structure. However I've come up with even better way to do that which came to me while looking at @Mike Brennan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6633651/355230) to another JSON-related question [How to get string objects instead of Unicode from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956867/how-to-get-string-objects-instead-of-unicode-from-json)

The basic idea is to use the `object_hook` parameter that [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) accepts just to watch what is being decoded and check for the sought-after value.

**Note:** This will only work if the representation is of a JSON [`object`](https://www.json.org) (i.e. something enclosed in [curly braces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket#Curly_brackets) `{}`), as in your sample.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import json

def find_values(id, json_repr):
    results = []

    def _decode_dict(a_dict):
        try:
            results.append(a_dict[id])
        except KeyError:
            pass
        return a_dict

    json.loads(json_repr, object_hook=_decode_dict) # Return value ignored.
    return results

json_repr = '{"P1": "ss", "Id": 1234, "P2": {"P1": "cccc"}, "P3": [{"P1": "aaa"}]}'
print(find_values('P1', json_repr))
```

(Python 3) output:

```
['cccc', 'aaa', 'ss']
```

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue just the other day. I wound up just searching through the entire object and accounted for both lists and dicts. The following snippets allows you to search for the *first* occurrence of a multiple keys.

```
import json

def deep_search(needles, haystack):
    found = {}
    if type(needles) != type([]):
        needles = [needles]

    if type(haystack) == type(dict()):
        for needle in needles:
            if needle in haystack.keys():
                found[needle] = haystack[needle]
            elif len(haystack.keys()) > 0:
                for key in haystack.keys():
                    result = deep_search(needle, haystack[key])
                    if result:
                        for k, v in result.items():
                            found[k] = v
    elif type(haystack) == type([]):
        for node in haystack:
            result = deep_search(needles, node)
            if result:
                for k, v in result.items():
                    found[k] = v
    return found

deep_search(["P1", "P3"], json.loads(json_string))
```

It returns a dict with the keys being the keys searched for. Haystack is expected to be a Python object already, so you have to do json.loads before passing it to deep_search.

Any comments for optimization are welcomed!

Comment: I know that this is an old answer but I just wanted to say that I adapted your solution by checking `len(needles) == len(found)` in both loops to cut the execution short in the case that I had already found all keys.

Comment: Awesome answer. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10):

Using `json` to convert the json to Python objects and then going through recursively works best.  This example *does* include going through lists.

```
import json
def get_all(myjson, key):
    if type(myjson) == str:
        myjson = json.loads(myjson)
    if type(myjson) is dict:
        for jsonkey in myjson:
            if type(myjson[jsonkey]) in (list, dict):
                get_all(myjson[jsonkey], key)
            elif jsonkey == key:
                print myjson[jsonkey]
    elif type(myjson) is list:
        for item in myjson:
            if type(item) in (list, dict):
                get_all(item, key)
```

Answer (score 6):

Converting the JSON to Python and recursively searching is by far the easiest:

```
def findall(v, k):
  if type(v) == type({}):
     for k1 in v:
         if k1 == k:
            print v[k1]
         findall(v[k1], k)

findall(json.loads(a), 'P1')
```

(where a is the string)

The example code ignores arrays.  Adding that is left as an exercise.

Comment: @lichengwu -- As I wrote, "The example code ignores arrays. Adding that is left as an exercise."  Add an `elif`.

Answer (score 5):

Bearing in mind that json is simply a string, using regular expressions with look-ahead and look-behind can accomplish this task very quickly.

Typically, the json would have been extracted from a request to external api, so code to show how that would work has been included but commented out.

```
import re
#import requests
#import json

#r1 = requests.get( ... url to some api ...)
#JSON = str(json.loads(r1.text))
JSON = """
 {
  "P1": "ss",
  "Id": 1234,
  "P2": {
      "P1": "cccc"
  },
  "P3": [
     {
          "P1": "aaa"
     }
  ]
 }
"""
rex1  = re.compile('(?<=\"P1\": \")[a-zA-Z_\- ]+(?=\")')
rex2 = rex1.findall(JSON)  
print(rex2)

#['ss', 'cccc', 'aaa']
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's any way of finding all values associated with P1 without iterating over the whole structure. Here's a recursive way to do it that first deserializes the JSON object into an equivalent Python object. To simplify things most of the work is done via a recursive private nested function.

```
import json

try:
    STRING_TYPE = basestring
except NameError:
    STRING_TYPE = str  # Python 3

def find_values(id, obj):
    results = []

    def _find_values(id, obj):
        try:
            for key, value in obj.items():  # dict?
                if key == id:
                    results.append(value)
                elif not isinstance(value, STRING_TYPE):
                    _find_values(id, value)
        except AttributeError:
            pass

        try:
            for item in obj:  # iterable?
                if not isinstance(item, STRING_TYPE):
                    _find_values(id, item)
        except TypeError:
            pass

    if not isinstance(obj, STRING_TYPE):
        _find_values(id, obj)
    return results

json_repr = '{"P1": "ss", "Id": 1234, "P2": {"P1": "cccc"}, "P3": [{"P1": "aaa"}]}'

obj = json.loads(json_repr)
print(find_values('P1', obj))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a generator to search the object after json.load().

Code example from my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39016088/5250939

```
def item_generator(json_input, lookup_key):
    if isinstance(json_input, dict):
        for k, v in json_input.iteritems():
            if k == lookup_key:
                yield v
            else:
                for child_val in item_generator(v, lookup_key):
                    yield child_val
    elif isinstance(json_input, list):
        for item in json_input:
            for item_val in item_generator(item, lookup_key):
                yield item_val
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but no answer answered 100%, so this was my solution:

**what it does:**

- recursive algorithm;
- list search;
- object search;
- returns all the results it finds in the tree;
- returns the id of the parent in the key

**suggestions:**

- study Depth First Search and Breadth First Search;
- if your json is too big, recursion may be a problem, research stack algorithm

```py
   @staticmethod
    def search_into_json_myversion(jsondata, searchkey, parentkeyname: str = None) -> list:
        found = []

        if type(jsondata) is list:
            for element in jsondata:
                val = Tools.search_into_json_myversion(element, searchkey, parentkeyname=parentkeyname)
                if len(val) != 0:
                    found = found + val
        elif type(jsondata) is dict:
            if searchkey in jsondata.keys():
                pathkey = parentkeyname + '->' + searchkey if parentkeyname != None else searchkey
                found.append({pathkey: jsondata[searchkey]})
            else:
                for key, value in jsondata.items():
                    val = Tools.search_into_json_myversion(value, searchkey, parentkeyname=key)
                    if len(val) != 0:
                        found = found + val

        return found
```