# Python replace values in unknown structure JSON file

Tags: python, json

Say that I have a JSON file whose structure is either unknown or may change overtime - I want to replace all values of "REPLACE_ME" with a string of my choice in Python.

Everything I have found assumes I know the structure. For example, I can read the JSON in with `json.load` and walk through the dictionary to do replacements then write it back. This assumes I know Key names, structure, etc.

How can I replace ALL of a given string value in a JSON file with something else?

Comment: something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882138/replace-value-in-json-file-for-key-which-can-be-nested-by-n-levels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* load the JSON file into a dictionary and recurse through that to find the proper values ***but*** that's unnecessary muscle flexing.

The best way is to simply treat the file as a string and do the replacements that way.

```
json_file = 'my_file.json'
with open(json_file) as f:
    file_data = f.read()

file_data = file_data.replace('REPLACE_ME', 'new string')
<...>

with open(json_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(file_data)

json_data = json.loads(file_data)
```

From here the file can be re-written and you can continue to use `json_data` as a dict.

Answer (score 7):

This function recursively replaces all strings which equal the value `original` with the value `new`.

This function works on the python structure - but of course you can use it on a json file - by using `json.load`

It doesn't replace keys in the dictionary - just the values.

```
def nested_replace( structure, original, new ):
    if type(structure) == list:
        return [nested_replace( item, original, new) for item in structure]

    if type(structure) == dict:
        return {key : nested_replace(value, original, new)
                     for key, value in structure.items() }

    if structure == original:
        return new
    else:
        return structure

d = [ 'replace', {'key1': 'replace', 'key2': ['replace', 'don\'t replace'] } ]
new_d = nested_replace(d, 'replace', 'now replaced')
print(new_d)
['now replaced', {'key1': 'now replaced', 'key2': ['now replaced', "don't replace"]}]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think there's no big risk if you want to replace any key or value enclosed with quotes (since quotes are escaped in json unless they are part of a string delimiter).

I would dump the structure, perform a `str.replace` (with double quotes), and parse again:

```
import json

d = { 'foo': {'bar' : 'hello'}}

d = json.loads(json.dumps(d).replace('"hello"','"hi"'))

print(d)
```

result:

```
{'foo': {'bar': 'hi'}}
```

I wouldn't risk to replace parts of strings or strings without quotes, because it could change other parts of the file. I can't think of an example where replacing a string without double quotes can change something else.

There are "clean" solutions like adapting from [Replace value in JSON file for key which can be nested by n levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882138/replace-value-in-json-file-for-key-which-can-be-nested-by-n-levels) but is it worth the effort? Depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

Why not modify the file directly instead of treating it as a JSON?

```
with open('filepath') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    line = line.replace('REPLACE_ME', 'whatever')
    with open('filepath_new', 'a') as f:
        f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well that depends, if you want to place all the strings entitled "REPLACE_ME" with the same string you can use this. The for loop loops through all the keys in the dictionary and then you can use the keys to select each value in the dictionary. If it is equal to your replacement string it will replace it with the string you want.

```
search_string = "REPLACE_ME"
replacement = "SOME STRING"
test = {"test1":"REPLACE_ME", "test2":"REPLACE_ME", "test3":"REPLACE_ME", "test4":"REPLACE_ME","test5":{"test6":"REPLACE_ME"}}


def replace_nested(test):

    for key,value in test.items():

        if type(value) is dict:
            replace_nested(value)
        else:
            if value==search_string:
                test[key] = replacement


replace_nested(test)
print(test)
```

Comment: This assumes the JSON has no nesting and `test` is a dictionary, not a JSON file

Comment: I added a recursive function to include nested dicts. Can you convert the  JSON to a dictionary?

Comment: it doesn't need to be a dictionary - even a list can be iterated through.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem in a dynamic way, I have obtained to use the same json file to declare the variables that we want to replace.

Json File :

```
{
"properties": {
"property_1": "value1",
"property_2": "value2"
},
"json_file_content": {
   "key_to_find": "{{property_1}} is my value"
   "dict1":{
       "key_to_find": "{{property_2}} is my other value"
   }
}
```

Python code (references [Replace value in JSON file for key which can be nested by n levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882138/replace-value-in-json-file-for-key-which-can-be-nested-by-n-levels)):

```
import json    
def fixup(self, a_dict:dict, k:str, subst_dict:dict) -> dict:
"""
function inspired by another answers linked below
""" 
    for key in a_dict.keys():
        if key == k:
            for s_k, s_v in subst_dict.items():
                a_dict[key] = a_dict[key].replace("{{"+s_k+"}}",s_v)
        elif type(a_dict[key]) is dict:
            fixup(a_dict[key], k, subst_dict)
# ...
file_path = "my/file/path"
if path.exists(file_path):
   with open(file_path, 'rt') as f:
   json_dict = json.load(f)
   fixup(json_dict ["json_file_content"],"key_to_find",json_dict ["properties"])
   print(json_dict) # json with variables resolved
else:
   print("file not found")
```

Hope it helps