# How to change the value of a JSON list?

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I know for fact that this question has been asked before. I looked at the following posts:

[Python replace values in unknown structure JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50631393/python-replace-values-in-unknown-structure-json-file)

[How to find and replace a part of a value in json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077503/how-to-find-and-replace-a-part-of-a-value-in-json-file/53078032)

https://pretagteam.com/question/how-to-replace-a-value-in-json-file-using-python

[How to find and replace a part of a value in json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53077503/how-to-find-and-replace-a-part-of-a-value-in-json-file/53078032) (Somehow this is what I am looking for but it does not fit my problem with the links being different and stored all under "latest")

and much more contributions, however I am still stuck.

I have a simple JSON structure like this:

```py
{
  "guild1": {
    "latest": [
      "link1",
      "link2"
    ],
    "channel": channel_here
  },
  "guild2": {
    "latest": [
      "link"
    ],
    "channel": channel_here
  }
}
```

I found a way to iterate over the entries and print the list in which the condition is found, for example:

```py
# searching for link 1
["link1", "link2", "link3"] # here link 1 for example is found in one of the list entries
["link5"] -> This for example does not match what I am looking for, I can ignore this
```

If found, I simply want to replace it (just `link1`) with another before defined value. I tried to iterate over the `keys` of the found list but was not able to `.replace` it or something else. The key which matches my search criteria is printed out, but I can't do anything else with it. Is it even possible to change the entry in a list that easy?

*Mostly I also got the following error which I also looked up but did not get any did not get any wiser:*

```py
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Here is how I search for the list end the "entries":

```py
if defined_link in data[searchloop]['latest']: # data is my JSON file, searchloop the for-loop
    for key in data[searchloop]['latest']: # Get all the matching keys
        if key == defined_link: # Get the key I am looking for
```

Maybe someone else can help me here!

Comment: You say you tried and did several things, but you didn't provide any Python code, other than two literals for lists of strings - can you please provide a sample of your code, explain what happens and what you expected instead?

Comment: @Grismar Sorry, was just editing the post. Have another look!

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you'd like to find any occurrences of any of `["link1", "link2", "link3"]` and replace them with something else? What do you want to replace them with? Do you want them replaced in an and all 'guilds'?

Comment: @Grismar I am already able to find all links that belong to my search criterion with this provided loop. I would like to replace these found links then with a new link, for this I simply took `"https://www.google.de/"` as a test, but of course nothing happened there. If found in every "guild", I want to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

This code would change one value in a list (here 'link1') to another:

```
L = ["link1", "link2", "link3"]
L[L.index('link1')] = 'someOtherValue'
```

After this you would see that L changed to ["someOtherValue", "link2", "link3"]

You first find at which index is 'link1', let's say you get back 3. So, you know you have to change the value of L[3]. Now it's simple. Do L[3] = 'someOtherValue'.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks! 
Do you know by any chance if indexing could possibly pull on the performance?

Comment: .index() function is not indexing but searching for a value in the list, which happens to be "link1" in the above example. And the time complexity is O(n) (most probably, only 99% sure). So, yes, searching a list takes a toll on performance. But depends on how big the list is (O(n)) and how many times would this function be called by users on the server.

Comment: This code runs every 30 seconds, would need to test it a bit more to be sure it could work out. It would not have more than 10000 "links" though

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try
`list.append(i)`
It will work I faced same problem

For example:

```
string = "Hello World!"

list = []

for i in string:

     list.append(string[i])

print(list)
```

Comment: `appending` in this case is adding a new value for me, if I understood your code in the direct way. I want to replace something in a list though.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each guild in the json structure.

Iterate over each link in that guild's "latest" list.

If the link matches, assign that list item to something else.

```
for guild in jsonstructure:
    for i in range(len(jsonstructure[guild]['latest'])):
        if jsonstructure[guild]['latest'][i] == 'something':
            jsonstructure[guild]['latest'][i] = 'new thing'
```

Comment: Hey John, thanks for your answer. This seems like a workable answer, too. Do you think If I have large lists, I will lose performance by looping over the JSON over and over again? Otherwise I would prefer this method as the answer by `Kushal Kumar` could take a lot of performance.