# Read a dict of dicts in a list

Tags: python, json, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I would like to read all `source` for an `id` in a json file that looks like this.
One `id` can have two sources, sometimes zero sources.

```
[ 
    {
        "trailers": {
            "quicktime": [], 
            "youtube": [
                {
                    "source": "source1", 
                    "type": "Trailer", 
                    "name": "Vf", 
                    "size": "HD"
                },
        {
                    "source": "source2", 
                    "type": "Trailer", 
                    "name": "Vf", 
                    "size": "HD"
                }
            ], 
            "id": 57417
        }, 

    {
        "trailers": {
            "quicktime": [], 
            "youtube": [], 
            "id": 57418
        }
]
```

I tried many solutions and I stopped in this one , and it doesn't work also :

```
from itertools import chain
trailers = {}
for item in j:        
    if item['trailers']:
        e = item['trailers']
        for k,value in e.iteritems():
            if k == "youtube":
                for each_dict in value:
                    for innerk, innerv in each_dict.iteritems():
                        if innerk == "source" :
                            trailers = dict(trailers.items() , {'trailer' : 'None'}.iteritems())                                                                
                        else:
                            trailers = {'trailer' : 'None'}
```

**Edit :** 
I would like to see this result :

```
57417, source1, source2
57418, None
```

Do you have suggestions ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Find all trailers on YouTube?

Comment: And what output do you expect?

Comment: Umm... have you considered `import json`?

Comment: The output that I would like to see is :
`57417, source1, source2` ans `57418, None`
Of course I imported `json` and everything works except this part .

Comment: You're a bit vague in describing what you want. I have a hunch that your question is probably similar to the question posed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048948/how-can-i-use-python-finding-particular-json-value-by-key).

Comment: @4m1nh4j1: You need to be **explicit** in what you want. You want to map trailer `id` keys to a list of sources? Only YouTube sources or also Quicktime?

Comment: There are brace imbalences in the json that you've posted. Please fix

Comment: Yes, map trailer id keys to a list `id` sources , only with youtube.

Comment: I'd not set an empty result to `None`; make it a consistent format, and an empty list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding all trailers on YouTube:

```
trailers = {film['trailers']['id']: [source['source'] for source in film['trailers'].get('youtube', [])] 
            for film in j}
```

This produces:

```
>>> {film['trailers']['id']: [source['source'] for source in film['trailers'].get('youtube', [])] 
...             for film in j}
{57417: ['source1', 'source2'], 57418: []}
```

Comment: @SteveJessop: Nested list comprehension there. But I was tripping over what is a list and what is a dictionary there first. All working now.