# Python find JSON in HTML and get select values

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

Gah. I've spent a fair amount of time trying to find how to do this both properly and even hackishly, and I am just stumped. I have 2500+ HTML files that I've downloaded from a site, and I need only to extract a limited amount of information from any given page: the title of the talk described by the page (so I can collate this data with a giant CSV we already have), and then the event at which a given talk was given, and the date on which the talk was published.

The HTML for these pages is sprawling and filled with `<script>` elements. I want only the one that is followed by a `q`. The line that starts this block looks like this:

```
<script>q("talkPage.init", {
```

What follows is quite a bit of data. I need only the three items that look like this:

```
"event":"TEDGlobal 2005",
"filmed":1120694400,
"published":1158019860,
```

Luckily, `"filmed"` and `"published"` only occur once in this large block, but `"event"` occurs several times. It's always the same, so I don't care which of these any script grabs.

My thought was to use **BeautifulSoup** to find the `<script>q` element and then pass that onto the **json** module to parse, but I cannot figure out hot to tell **soup** to grab the `<script>` element followed by a q -- classes and ids are easy. Followed by ... not so much.

To begin working on the JSON portion, I've created a text file which has only the contents of the `<script>q` element in it, but I confess that getting the **json** module to load this is not working terribly well.

The code I have for the experiment first loads the text file with the JSON block I'm interested in, and then tries to decode it so I can do other things with it:

```
import json

text = open('dawkins_script_element.txt', 'r').read()
data = json.loads(text)
```

But clearly the JSON decoder doesn't like what I have, because it throws a `ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. Bah!

Here's what the first three lines of this script element looks like:

```
<script>q("talkPage.init", {
"el": "[data-talk-page]",
"__INITIAL_DATA__":
```

And that is where I am at the current moment. Any light that can be shed on either the **soup** or the **json** to get this done would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the full context, here's a poor man's attempt:

Assuming your html looks something like this:

```
<script>foo</script>
<script>bar</script>
<script>q("talkPage.init",{
"foo1":"bar1",
"event":"TEDGlobal 2005",
"filmed":1120694400,
"published":1158019860,
"foo2":"bar2"
})</script>
<script>q("talkPage.init",{
"foo1":"bar1",
"event":"foobar",
"filmed":123,
"published":456,
"foo2":"bar2"
})</script>
<script>foo</script>
<script>bar</script>
```

You can code like this:

```
res = requests.get(url) # your link here
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.content)
my_list = [i.string.lstrip('q("talkPage.init", ').rstrip(')') for i in soup.select('script') if i.string and i.string.startswith('q')]

# my_list should now be filled with all the json text that is from a <script> tag followed by a 'q'
# note that I lstrip and rstrip on the script based no your sample (assuming there's a closing bracket), but if the convention is different you'll need to update that accordingly.

#...#
my_jsons = []
for json_string in my_list:
    my_jsons.append(json.loads(json_string))

# parse your my_jsons however you want.
```

Then you can start interpreting the jsons:

```
print(my_jsons[0]['event'])
print(my_jsons[0]['filmed'])
print(my_jsons[0]['published'])

# Output:
# TEDGlobal 2005
# 1120694400
# 1158019860
```

There's a lot of assumptions here.  That's assuming all your texts within `<script>q` elements will always be starting with `q("talkPage.init",` and ending with a `)`.  Also it's assuming the texts returned follow the json format for your next stage of parsing.  I'm also assuming you have knowledge of how to parse the json results.

Comment: I'm working with both these answers to see which one works best. I'll have more tomorrow first thing. Thanks for such a thoughtful answer!

Comment: Working through this, I have to use `soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html5lib")` because when I try, `soup = BeautifulSoup(text.content)`, I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'`. I then use the list comprehension, which produces a list one item long, but it has the section we want. Right now, I'm stumbling on the JSON parsing, so that's what I will spend my morning working on. Thanks!

Comment: It depends what your original content is - if it was a `request` object (in my sample) then you'll want to get the text `content` for BeautifulSoup to parse.  In your case it seems yours is a `str` object so just passing the `str` itself is good enough.  If you're having trouble parsing the json I recommend you get a bit more info on the [`json` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Comment: I've definitely learned how fussy the JSON module is. Some may find this pretty ugly, but to get the JSON module to parse the string I had to do this: `pre_json = '{"' + "".join(my_list)` and then `my_json = json.loads(pre_json)`

Comment: @JohnLaudun that sounds more like the string being passed to the `json` module isn't properly formatted.  You'll want to ensure the string result you parsed from the html can be read as a dictionary.  If it's missing the `{` then it might have been stripped from the html parsing by mistake.

Comment: I confess I'm coming to hate the `json` module: it wasn't parsing a bracketed series `[{"spam":"eggs" ... }], so I got rid of the brackets using `translation_table = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, '[]'), None)`, but now it appears to be choking on a perfectly good property. I'm going to restart the kernel for this notebook and see what happens...

Comment: So the problem is an embedded list inside the JSON on the page: `[{'more_resources': None, 'take_action': None, ... 'event': 'TEDGlobal 2005'}]`. The `json` module wants double quotes.

Comment: The `json` module is actually pretty easy to use IMO.  Parsing nested jsons might be a pain but it is what it is.  You can easily fix the single quotes by doing a `.replace("'",'"')` (first param is single quote in double quotes, second is double quote in single quotes) on the text before you pass onto `json`.  For parsing, you might want to look into relevant threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028979/recursive-iteration-through-nested-json-for-specific-key-in-python).

Comment: I agree that it's probably easy when you have proper JSON. Sadly, I don't. I thought about replacing the single quotes with double quotes, but I have double quotes within some of the values, so I was pretty sure it would break. What I've done with, for now, is turning the value that is in fact a one-item list into a string, splitting on commas, and then filtering on some regex for the properties I want. It ain't pretty, but if it will work for the 2500 texts I have, I'll like it well enough.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex expression to match the part you want.

```
import re
# Filters the script-tag all the way to end ')' of q.
scipt_tag = re.findall(r'<script>q\((?s:.+)\)', t)
json_content = re.search(r'(?<=q\()(?s:.+)\)', script_tag[0]).group()
json_content = json_content[:-1]  # Strip last ')'
```

To find the stuff you need you can either use pythons json library to parse it or match the last things with what you want. Since `filmed` and `published` are unique and `event` doesn't differ (as I understood?)

```
import json
json_content = json.loads(json_content)
json_content['event']  # or whatever
```

**OR**

```
def get_val(a):
re.search('r(?<=' + a + r'\": )(.+)').group(0)
```

The latter needs to be filtered a bit to remove trailing `]"` and preceding `"[`, or what not you want from it.

I've heard beautifulsoup is also a good library for matching html-stuff, but im not so familiar with it.

Comment: I like the idea of doing this with `regex`, which has always exceeded my grasp, but the line `script_tag = re.findall(r'<script>q\((?s:.+)\)', text)` throws an `error: unknown extension`. It looks like it doesn't like the closing parenthesis? `739                     if char == ")":
    740                         break
--> 741                     raise error("unknown extension")`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the script I ended up using, with real thanks to both @Idlehands and @Three. To reach into the weird single-quoted JSON, I took the entire JSON element and read it into a list, split on commas. It's a hack, but it mostly works.

```
def get_metadata(the_file):

    # Load the modules we need
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import json
    import re
    from datetime import datetime

    # Read the file, load it into BS, then grab section we want
    text = the_file.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "html5lib")
    my_list = [i.string.lstrip('q("talkPage.init", {\n\t"el": "[data-talk-page]",\n\t "__INITIAL_DATA__":')
               .rstrip('})')
               for i in soup.select('script') 
               if i.string and i.string.startswith('q')]

    # Read first layer of JSON and get out those elements we want
    pre_json = '{"' + "".join(my_list)
    my_json = json.loads(pre_json)
    slug = my_json['slug']
    vcount = my_json['viewed_count']
    event = my_json['event']

    # Read second layer of JSON and get out listed elements:
    properties = "filmed,published" # No spaces between terms!
    talks_listed = str(my_json['talks']).split(",")
    regex_list = [".*("+i+").*" for i in properties.split(",")]
    matches = []
    for e in regex_list:
        filtered = filter(re.compile(e).match, talks_listed)
        indexed = "".join(filtered).split(":")[1]
        matches.append(indexed)
    filmed = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(matches[0])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    # published = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(matches[1])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    return slug, vcount, event, filmed, #published
```