# I'm not understanding how to iterate through a json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing

I'm new to Python and am trying my hand at Python3.7.

I'm running this on Windows 10 in a PyCharm environment

I have a json file that contains a bunch of network data from one of my appliances. Its imaginatively called 'network.json' I am trying to return the 'host names from the json object. The particular hostnames im trying to return are in the 'probes' section I have tried referencing it as print([instances][probes]) but that does not return what I'm looking for. I have tried looking at examples on here and other sites but I just cant get my brain around it. Any help would be much appreciated.

My code is below.

```
import json

with open('network.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

print('Appliance OS Code is ', data["applianceOSCode"])
print('Version is: ', data["version"])

for hostname in data.items():
    print(hostname)
```

The output of the code is as follows

```
Appliance OS Code is  x
Version is:  3.0.8 (oc6d6f)
('time', '2018-09-26 09:34')
('installed', '2018-08-13')
('version', '3.0.8 (oc6d6f)')
('modelsUpdated', '2018-08-30 10:12:41')
('modelPackageVersion', '3.0.8.1~20180726095847~gc6d747')
('hostname', 'at-40-99-29')
('inoculation', True)
('applianceOSCode', 'x')
('diskSpaceUsed_ssd', 77)
('diskSpaceUsed_var', 77)
('type', 'unifiedView')
('load', 29)
('cpu', 39)
('memoryUsed', 49)
('instances', {'at-40-99-29': {'id': 1, 'version': '3.0.8 (oc6d6f)', 'label': 'Master 1', 'hostname': 'at-40-99-29', 'time': '2018-09-26 09:34', 'applianceOSCode': 'x', 'diskSpaceUsed_ssd': 77, 'diskSpaceUsed_var': 77, 'type': 'master', 'diskUtilization': 3, 'load': 31, 'cpu': 34, 'memoryUsed': 49, 'darkflowQueue': 280, 'networkInterfacesReceived_eth0': 4211426005033, 'networkInterfacesReceived_eth1': 1143, 'networkInterfacesReceived_eth2': 72400, 'networkInterfacesReceived_eth3': 24110, 'networkInterfacesReceived_eth6': 1258046541112778, 'networkInterfacesTransmitted_eth0': 326798655431, 'bandwidthCurrent': 2909592901, 'bandwidthCurrentString': '2.91 Gbps', 'bandwidthAverage': 2473968000, 'bandwidthAverageString': '2.47 Gbps', 'bandwidth7DayPeak': 5825516278, 'bandwidth7DayPeakString': '5.83 Gbps', 'bandwidth2WeekPeak': 6762252000, 'bandwidth2WeekPeakString': '6.76 Gbps', 'processedBandwidthCurrent': 2133360348, 'processedBandwidthCurrentString': '2.13 Gbps', 'processedBandwidthAverage': 1838597093, 'processedBandwidthAverageString': '1.84 Gbps', 'processedBandwidth7DayPeak': 5020716464, 'processedBandwidth7DayPeakString': '5.02 Gbps', 'processedBandwidth2WeekPeak': 5156920844, 'processedBandwidth2WeekPeakString': '5.16 Gbps', 'probes': {'10.10.10.65': {'id': 1, 'version': '3.0.8 (oc6d6f)', 'label': 'Slave-1', 'hostname': 'at-40-99-13', 'time': '2018-09-26 09:34', 'applianceOSCode': 'x', 'diskSpaceUsed_var': 14, 'type': 'probe', 'diskUtilization': 1, 'load': 2, 'cpu': 2, 'memoryUsed': 20, 'networkInterfacesReceived_eth0': 27412523062, 'networkInterfacesReceived_eth1': 651092285, 'networkInterfacesReceived_eth2': 49591528818957, 'networkInterfacesTransmitted_eth0': 171737198513, 'bandwidthCurrent': 13291031, 'bandwidthCurrentString': '13.29 Mbps', 'bandwidthAverage': 35630000, 'bandwidthAverageString': '35.63 Mbps', 'bandwidth7DayPeak': 55076566, 'bandwidth7DayPeakString': '55.08 Mbps', 'bandwidth2WeekPeak': 55076566, 'bandwidth2WeekPeakString': '55.08 Mbps', 'processedBandwidthCurrent': 4166650, 'processedBandwidthCurrentString': '4.17 Mbps', 'processedBandwidthAverage': 8538720, 'processedBandwidthAverageString': '8.54 Mbps', 'processedBandwidth7DayPeak': 24348245, 'processedBandwidth7DayPeakString': '24.35 Mbps', 'processedBandwidth2WeekPeak': 24348245, 'processedBandwidth2WeekPeakString': '24.35 Mbps', 'connectionsPerMinuteCurrent': 483, 'connectionsPerMinuteAverage': 277, 'connectionsPerMinute7DayPeak': 5403, 'connectionsPerMinute2WeekPeak': 5653}, '10.20.10.65': {'id': 2, 'version': '3.0.8 (oc6d6f)', 'label': 'Slave-2', 'hostname': 'at-40-99-27', 'time': '2018-09-26 09:34', 'applianceOSCode': 'x', 'diskSpaceUsed_var': 6, 'type': 'probe', 'diskUtilization': 1, 'load': 37, 'cpu': 19, 'memoryUsed': 38, 'networkInterfacesReceived_eth0': 3482568854, 'networkInterfacesReceived_eth1': 1550011071785, 'networkInterfacesReceived_eth2': 1504270545, 'networkInterfacesReceived_eth3': 93304978255, 'networkInterfacesTransmitted_eth0': 5626326133, 'bandwidthCurrent': 4646553, 'bandwidthCurrentString': '4.65 Mbps', 'bandwidthAverage': 3822000, 'bandwidthAverageString': '3.82 Mbps', 'bandwidth7DayPeak': 8838037, 'bandwidth7DayPeakString': '8.84 Mbps', 'bandwidth2WeekPeak': 14856421, 'bandwidth2WeekPeakString': '14.86 Mbps', 'processedBandwidthCurrent': 2977386, 'processedBandwidthCurrentString': '2.98 Mbps', 'processedBandwidthAverage': 1695571, 'processedBandwidthAverageString': '1.70 Mbps', 'processedBandwidth7DayPeak': 6923804, 'processedBandwidth7DayPeakString': '6.92 Mbps', 'processedBandwidth2WeekPeak': 9804105, 'processedBandwidth2WeekPeakString': '9.80 Mbps', 'connectionsPerMinuteCurrent': 337, 'connectionsPerMinuteAverage': 130, 'connectionsPerMinute7DayPeak': 1267, 'connectionsPerMinute2WeekPeak': 1267}, '10.30.10.65': {'id': 3, 'version': '3.0.8 (oc6d6f)', 'label': 'Slave-3', 'hostname': 'at-40-99-07', 'time': '2018-09-26 09:34', 'applianceOSCode': 'x', 'diskSpaceUsed_var': 10, 'type': 'probe', 'diskUtilization': 1, 'load': 2, 'cpu': 2, 'memoryUsed': 42, 'networkInterfacesReceived_eth0': 11998964574, 'networkInterfacesReceived_eth1': 1806070454, 'networkInterfacesReceived_eth2': 5930999520394, 'networkInterfacesTransmitted_eth0': 35571240425, 'bandwidthCurrent': 4260499, 'bandwidthCurrentString': '4.26 Mbps', 'bandwidthAverage': 4902000, 'bandwidthAverageString': '4.90 Mbps', 'bandwidth7DayPeak': 31176831, 'bandwidth7DayPeakString': '31.18 Mbps', 'bandwidth2WeekPeak': 32870919, 'bandwidth2WeekPeakString': '32.87 Mbps', 'processedBandwidthCurrent': 2128477, 'processedBandwidthCurrentString': '2.13 Mbps', 'processedBandwidthAverage': 2543620, 'processedBandwidthAverageString': '2.54 Mbps', 'processedBandwidth7DayPeak': 20040857, 'processedBandwidth7DayPeakString': '20.04 Mbps', 'processedBandwidth2WeekPeak': 21523088, 'processedBandwidth2WeekPeakString': '21.52 Mbps', 'connectionsPerMinuteCurrent': 123, 'connectionsPerMinuteAverage': 139, 'connectionsPerMinute7DayPeak': 4278, 'connectionsPerMinute2WeekPeak': 4278}, '172.16.10.65': {'id': 4, 'version': '3.0.8 (oc6d6f)', 'label': 'Slave-4', 'hostname': 'at-40-99-16', 'time': '2018-09-26 09:34', 'applianceOSCode': 'x', 'diskSpaceUsed_var': 2, 'type': 'probe', 'diskUtilization': 1, 'load': 1, 'cpu': 1, 'memoryUsed': 13, 'networkInterfacesReceived_eth0': 3870679662, 'networkInterfacesReceived_eth1': 48903720901, 'networkInterfacesReceived_eth3': 1297581020, 'networkInterfacesTransmitted_eth0': 7182507049, 'bandwidthCurrent': 129172, 'bandwidthCurrentString': '129 kbps', 'bandwidthAverage': 115000, 'bandwidthAverageString': '115 kbps', 'bandwidth7DayPeak': 1754789, 'bandwidth7DayPeakString': '1.75 Mbps', 'bandwidth2WeekPeak': 2030839, 'bandwidth2WeekPeakString': '2.03 Mbps', 'processedBandwidthCurrent': 97945, 'processedBandwidthCurrentString': '98 kbps', 'processedBandwidthAverage': 89217, 'processedBandwidthAverageString': '89 kbps', 'processedBandwidth7DayPeak': 1411308, 'processedBandwidth7DayPeakString': '1.41 Mbps', 'processedBandwidth2WeekPeak': 1629578, 'processedBandwidth2WeekPeakString': '1.63 Mbps', 'connectionsPerMinuteCurrent': 30, 'connectionsPerMinuteAverage': 50, 'connectionsPerMinute7DayPeak': 4236, 'connectionsPerMinute2WeekPeak': 4651}}, 'connectionsPerMinuteCurrent': 127164, 'connectionsPerMinuteAverage': 118679, 'connectionsPerMinute7DayPeak': 192227, 'connectionsPerMinute2WeekPeak': 192227, 'operatingSystems': 26, 'newDevices4Weeks': 301, 'newDevices7Days': 59, 'newDevices24Hours': 10, 'newDevicesHour': 4, 'activeDevices4Weeks': 8248, 'activeDevices7Days': 7716, 'activeDevices24Hours': 7082, 'activeDevicesHour': 2673, 'deviceHostnames': 4825, 'deviceMACAddresses': 2040, 'deviceRecentIPChange': 31, 'models': 416, 'modelsBreached': 1324452, 'modelsSuppressed': 2924574, 'devicesModeled': 8248, 'recentUnidirectionalConnections': 0, 'mostRecentDHCPTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:34:00', 'mostRecentDNSTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:33:00', 'mostRecentBITTORRENTTraffic': '2018-09-24 06:09:00', 'mostRecentDCE_RPCTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:32:00', 'mostRecentDNP3Traffic': '2018-09-01 08:58:00', 'mostRecentDTLSTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:32:00', 'mostRecentFTPTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:32:00', 'mostRecentHTTPTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:33:00', 'mostRecentHTTPSTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:32:00', 'mostRecentIMAPTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:32:00', 'mostRecentIRCTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:29:00', 'mostRecentKERBEROSTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:32:00', 'mostRecentLDAPTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:32:00', 'mostRecentNTLMTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:08:00', 'mostRecentNTPTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:32:00', 'mostRecentRADIUSTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:32:00', 'mostRecentRDPTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:31:00', 'mostRecentRFBTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:32:00', 'mostRecentSIPTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:31:00', 'mostRecentSMBTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:32:00', 'mostRecentSMB1Traffic': '2018-09-26 09:32:00', 'mostRecentSMTPTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:31:00', 'mostRecentSNMPTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:33:00', 'mostRecentSOCKSTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:31:00', 'mostRecentSSDPTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:33:00', 'mostRecentSSHTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:32:00', 'mostRecentSSLTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:33:00', 'mostRecentXMPPTraffic': '2018-09-18 06:44:00', 'ignoreAnalysisCredentials': ['nagios', 'nmap', 'snort', 'some_service'], 'internalIPRangeList': ['10.0.0.0/8', '172.16.0.0/12'], 'internalIPRanges': 18, 'dnsServers': 1483, 'internalDomains': 2, 'internalAndExternalDomains': 8, 'proxyServers': 74, 'proxyServerIPs': ['10.10.10.10:80', '10.20.10.10:8080', '10.30.10.10:3128', '172.16.10.10:3128'], 'subnets': 4, 'subnetData': [{'network': '10.10.10.0/24', 'devices': 30, 'clientDevices': 64, 'mostRecentTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:00:00', 'mostRecentDHCP': '2018-09-26 09:00:00', 'dhcpQuality': 73, 'kerberosQuality': 38}, {'network': '10.20.10.0/24', 'devices': 70, 'clientDevices': 21, 'mostRecentTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:00:00', 'mostRecentDHCP': '2016-05-05 08:00:00'}, {'network': '10.30.10.0/24', 'devices': 15, 'clientDevices': 9, 'mostRecentTraffic': '2018-09-26 09:00:00', 'mostRecentDHCP': '2018-04-15 04:00:00', 'kerberosQuality': 2}, {'network': '172.16.10.0/24', 'devices': 1, 'clientDevices': 0, 'mostRecentTraffic': '2018-09-24 14:00:00', 'mostRecentDHCP': 'Never'}]}})
```

The Json file is as follows

```
 {
   "time": "2018-09-26 09:34",
   "installed": "2018-08-13",
   "version": "3.0.8 (oc6d6f)",
   "modelsUpdated": "2018-08-30 10:12:41",
   "modelPackageVersion": "3.0.8.1~20180726095847~gc6d747",
   "hostname": "at-40-99-29",
   "inoculation": true,
   "applianceOSCode": "x",
   "diskSpaceUsed_ssd": 77,
   "diskSpaceUsed_var": 77,
   "type": "unifiedView",
   "load": 29,
   "cpu": 39,
   "memoryUsed": 49,
   "instances": {
       "at-40-99-29": {
           "id": 1,
           "version": "3.0.8 (oc6d6f)",
           "label": "Master 1",
           "hostname": "at-40-99-29",
           "time": "2018-09-26 09:34",
           "applianceOSCode": "x",
           "diskSpaceUsed_ssd": 77,
           "diskSpaceUsed_var": 77,
           "type": "master",
           "diskUtilization": 3,
           "load": 31,
           "cpu": 34,
           "memoryUsed": 49,
           "darkflowQueue": 280,
           "networkInterfacesReceived_eth0": 4211426005033,
           "networkInterfacesReceived_eth1": 1143,
           "networkInterfacesReceived_eth2": 72400,
           "networkInterfacesReceived_eth3": 24110,
           "networkInterfacesReceived_eth6": 1258046541112778,
           "networkInterfacesTransmitted_eth0": 326798655431,
           "bandwidthCurrent": 2909592901,
           "bandwidthCurrentString": "2.91 Gbps",
           "bandwidthAverage": 2473968000,
           "bandwidthAverageString": "2.47 Gbps",
           "bandwidth7DayPeak": 5825516278,
           "bandwidth7DayPeakString": "5.83 Gbps",
           "bandwidth2WeekPeak": 6762252000,
           "bandwidth2WeekPeakString": "6.76 Gbps",
           "processedBandwidthCurrent": 2133360348,
           "processedBandwidthCurrentString": "2.13 Gbps",
           "processedBandwidthAverage": 1838597093,
           "processedBandwidthAverageString": "1.84 Gbps",
           "processedBandwidth7DayPeak": 5020716464,
           "processedBandwidth7DayPeakString": "5.02 Gbps",
           "processedBandwidth2WeekPeak": 5156920844,
           "processedBandwidth2WeekPeakString": "5.16 Gbps",
           "probes": {
               "10.10.10.65": {
                   "id": 1,
                   "version": "3.0.8 (oc6d6f)",
                   "label": "Slave-1",
                   "hostname": "at-40-99-13",
                   "time": "2018-09-26 09:34",
                   "applianceOSCode": "x",
                   "diskSpaceUsed_var": 14,
                   "type": "probe",
                   "diskUtilization": 1,
                   "load": 2,
                   "cpu": 2,
                   "memoryUsed": 20,
                   "networkInterfacesReceived_eth0": 27412523062,
                   "networkInterfacesReceived_eth1": 651092285,
                   "networkInterfacesReceived_eth2": 49591528818957,
                   "networkInterfacesTransmitted_eth0": 171737198513,
                   "bandwidthCurrent": 13291031,
                   "bandwidthCurrentString": "13.29 Mbps",
                   "bandwidthAverage": 35630000,
                   "bandwidthAverageString": "35.63 Mbps",
                   "bandwidth7DayPeak": 55076566,
                   "bandwidth7DayPeakString": "55.08 Mbps",
                   "bandwidth2WeekPeak": 55076566,
                   "bandwidth2WeekPeakString": "55.08 Mbps",
                   "processedBandwidthCurrent": 4166650,
                   "processedBandwidthCurrentString": "4.17 Mbps",
                   "processedBandwidthAverage": 8538720,
                   "processedBandwidthAverageString": "8.54 Mbps",
                   "processedBandwidth7DayPeak": 24348245,
                   "processedBandwidth7DayPeakString": "24.35 Mbps",
                   "processedBandwidth2WeekPeak": 24348245,
                   "processedBandwidth2WeekPeakString": "24.35 Mbps",
                   "connectionsPerMinuteCurrent": 483,
                   "connectionsPerMinuteAverage": 277,
                   "connectionsPerMinute7DayPeak": 5403,
                   "connectionsPerMinute2WeekPeak": 5653
               },
               "10.20.10.65": {
                   "id": 2,
                   "version": "3.0.8 (oc6d6f)",
                   "label": "Slave-2",
                   "hostname": "at-40-99-27",
                   "time": "2018-09-26 09:34",
                   "applianceOSCode": "x",
                   "diskSpaceUsed_var": 6,
                   "type": "probe",
                   "diskUtilization": 1,
                   "load": 37,
                   "cpu": 19,
                   "memoryUsed": 38,
                   "networkInterfacesReceived_eth0": 3482568854,
                   "networkInterfacesReceived_eth1": 1550011071785,
                   "networkInterfacesReceived_eth2": 1504270545,
                   "networkInterfacesReceived_eth3": 93304978255,
                   "networkInterfacesTransmitted_eth0": 5626326133,
                   "bandwidthCurrent": 4646553,
                   "bandwidthCurrentString": "4.65 Mbps",
                   "bandwidthAverage": 3822000,
                   "bandwidthAverageString": "3.82 Mbps",
                   "bandwidth7DayPeak": 8838037,
                   "bandwidth7DayPeakString": "8.84 Mbps",
                   "bandwidth2WeekPeak": 14856421,
                   "bandwidth2WeekPeakString": "14.86 Mbps",
                   "processedBandwidthCurrent": 2977386,
                   "processedBandwidthCurrentString": "2.98 Mbps",
                   "processedBandwidthAverage": 1695571,
                   "processedBandwidthAverageString": "1.70 Mbps",
                   "processedBandwidth7DayPeak": 6923804,
                   "processedBandwidth7DayPeakString": "6.92 Mbps",
                   "processedBandwidth2WeekPeak": 9804105,
                   "processedBandwidth2WeekPeakString": "9.80 Mbps",
                   "connectionsPerMinuteCurrent": 337,
                   "connectionsPerMinuteAverage": 130,
                   "connectionsPerMinute7DayPeak": 1267,
                   "connectionsPerMinute2WeekPeak": 1267
               },
               "10.30.10.65": {
                   "id": 3,
                   "version": "3.0.8 (oc6d6f)",
                   "label": "Slave-3",
                   "hostname": "at-40-99-07",
                   "time": "2018-09-26 09:34",
                   "applianceOSCode": "x",
                   "diskSpaceUsed_var": 10,
                   "type": "probe",
                  "diskUtilization": 1,
                   "load": 2,
                   "cpu": 2,
                   "memoryUsed": 42,
                   "networkInterfacesReceived_eth0": 11998964574,
                   "networkInterfacesReceived_eth1": 1806070454,
                   "networkInterfacesReceived_eth2": 5930999520394,
                   "networkInterfacesTransmitted_eth0": 35571240425,
                   "bandwidthCurrent": 4260499,
                   "bandwidthCurrentString": "4.26 Mbps",
                   "bandwidthAverage": 4902000,
                   "bandwidthAverageString": "4.90 Mbps",
                   "bandwidth7DayPeak": 31176831,
                   "bandwidth7DayPeakString": "31.18 Mbps",
                   "bandwidth2WeekPeak": 32870919,
                   "bandwidth2WeekPeakString": "32.87 Mbps",
                   "processedBandwidthCurrent": 2128477,
                   "processedBandwidthCurrentString": "2.13 Mbps",
                   "processedBandwidthAverage": 2543620,
                   "processedBandwidthAverageString": "2.54 Mbps",
                   "processedBandwidth7DayPeak": 20040857,
                   "processedBandwidth7DayPeakString": "20.04 Mbps",
                   "processedBandwidth2WeekPeak": 21523088,
                   "processedBandwidth2WeekPeakString": "21.52 Mbps",
                   "connectionsPerMinuteCurrent": 123,
                   "connectionsPerMinuteAverage": 139,
                   "connectionsPerMinute7DayPeak": 4278,
                   "connectionsPerMinute2WeekPeak": 4278
               },
               "172.16.10.65": {
                   "id": 4,
                   "version": "3.0.8 (oc6d6f)",
                   "label": "Slave-4",
                   "hostname": "at-40-99-16",
                   "time": "2018-09-26 09:34",
                   "applianceOSCode": "x",
                   "diskSpaceUsed_var": 2,
                   "type": "probe",
                   "diskUtilization": 1,
                   "load": 1,
                   "cpu": 1,
                   "memoryUsed": 13,
                   "networkInterfacesReceived_eth0": 3870679662,
                   "networkInterfacesReceived_eth1": 48903720901,
                   "networkInterfacesReceived_eth3": 1297581020,
                   "networkInterfacesTransmitted_eth0": 7182507049,
                   "bandwidthCurrent": 129172,
                   "bandwidthCurrentString": "129 kbps",
                   "bandwidthAverage": 115000,
                   "bandwidthAverageString": "115 kbps",
                   "bandwidth7DayPeak": 1754789,
                   "bandwidth7DayPeakString": "1.75 Mbps",
                   "bandwidth2WeekPeak": 2030839,
                   "bandwidth2WeekPeakString": "2.03 Mbps",
                   "processedBandwidthCurrent": 97945,
                   "processedBandwidthCurrentString": "98 kbps",
                   "processedBandwidthAverage": 89217,
                   "processedBandwidthAverageString": "89 kbps",
                   "processedBandwidth7DayPeak": 1411308,
                   "processedBandwidth7DayPeakString": "1.41 Mbps",
                   "processedBandwidth2WeekPeak": 1629578,
                   "processedBandwidth2WeekPeakString": "1.63 Mbps",
                   "connectionsPerMinuteCurrent": 30,
                   "connectionsPerMinuteAverage": 50,
                   "connectionsPerMinute7DayPeak": 4236,
                   "connectionsPerMinute2WeekPeak": 4651
               }
           },
           "connectionsPerMinuteCurrent": 127164,
           "connectionsPerMinuteAverage": 118679,
           "connectionsPerMinute7DayPeak": 192227,
           "connectionsPerMinute2WeekPeak": 192227,
           "operatingSystems": 26,
           "newDevices4Weeks": 301,
           "newDevices7Days": 59,
           "newDevices24Hours": 10,
           "newDevicesHour": 4,
           "activeDevices4Weeks": 8248,
           "activeDevices7Days": 7716,
           "activeDevices24Hours": 7082,
           "activeDevicesHour": 2673,
           "deviceHostnames": 4825,
           "deviceMACAddresses": 2040,
           "deviceRecentIPChange": 31,
           "models": 416,
           "modelsBreached": 1324452,
           "modelsSuppressed": 2924574,
           "devicesModeled": 8248,
           "recentUnidirectionalConnections": 0,
           "mostRecentDHCPTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:34:00",
           "mostRecentDNSTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:33:00",
           "mostRecentBITTORRENTTraffic": "2018-09-24 06:09:00",
           "mostRecentDCE_RPCTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:32:00",
           "mostRecentDNP3Traffic": "2018-09-01 08:58:00",
           "mostRecentDTLSTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:32:00",
           "mostRecentFTPTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:32:00",
           "mostRecentHTTPTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:33:00",
           "mostRecentHTTPSTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:32:00",
           "mostRecentIMAPTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:32:00",
           "mostRecentIRCTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:29:00",
           "mostRecentKERBEROSTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:32:00",
           "mostRecentLDAPTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:32:00",
           "mostRecentNTLMTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:08:00",
           "mostRecentNTPTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:32:00",
           "mostRecentRADIUSTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:32:00",
           "mostRecentRDPTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:31:00",
           "mostRecentRFBTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:32:00",
           "mostRecentSIPTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:31:00",
           "mostRecentSMBTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:32:00",
           "mostRecentSMB1Traffic": "2018-09-26 09:32:00",
           "mostRecentSMTPTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:31:00",
           "mostRecentSNMPTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:33:00",
           "mostRecentSOCKSTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:31:00",
           "mostRecentSSDPTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:33:00",
           "mostRecentSSHTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:32:00",
           "mostRecentSSLTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:33:00",
           "mostRecentXMPPTraffic": "2018-09-18 06:44:00",
           "ignoreAnalysisCredentials": [
               "nagios",
               "nmap",
               "snort",
               "some_service"
           ],
           "internalIPRangeList": [
               "10.0.0.0/8",
               "172.16.0.0/12"

           ],
           "internalIPRanges": 18,
           "dnsServers": 1483,
           "internalDomains": 2,
           "internalAndExternalDomains": 8,
           "proxyServers": 74,
           "proxyServerIPs": [
               "10.10.10.10:80",
               "10.20.10.10:8080",
               "10.30.10.10:3128",
               "172.16.10.10:3128"
           ],
           "subnets": 4,
           "subnetData": [
               {
                   "network": "10.10.10.0/24",
                   "devices": 30,
                   "clientDevices": 64,
                   "mostRecentTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:00:00",
                   "mostRecentDHCP": "2018-09-26 09:00:00",
                   "dhcpQuality": 73,
                   "kerberosQuality": 38
               },
               {
                   "network": "10.20.10.0/24",
                   "devices": 70,
                   "clientDevices": 21,
                   "mostRecentTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:00:00",
                   "mostRecentDHCP": "2016-05-05 08:00:00"
               },
               {
                   "network": "10.30.10.0/24",
                   "devices": 15,
                   "clientDevices": 9,
                   "mostRecentTraffic": "2018-09-26 09:00:00",
                   "mostRecentDHCP": "2018-04-15 04:00:00",
                   "kerberosQuality": 2
               },
               {
                   "network": "172.16.10.0/24",
                   "devices": 1,
                   "clientDevices": 0,
                   "mostRecentTraffic": "2018-09-24 14:00:00",
                   "mostRecentDHCP": "Never"
               }
           ]
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: change `for hostname in data.items():` to `for hostname in data["instances"]["at-40-99-29"]["probes"].items():`

Comment: Excellent. SO now I can see how I get down to the level I wish. How do I go about actually printing out specific fields from the returned daya. Say I wanted to print out Probes-> "label:value" key value pair?

Comment: A json is a dictionary, and in a dictionary is searched for the keys, not the values, so as my example, I first accessed an element by the key and then I realized that it was another dictionary so I accessed the next element by the key to where you want to go, if you want to access a key that can be at any level you should do the same but recursively, there is no method to do it directly, if you want to obtain an element by key-value you will have to get it first by the key and then check if it has the value.

Comment: Maybe the following will help you, there you will be able to iterate through all the keys at whatever level it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028979/recursive-iteration-through-nested-json-for-specific-key-in-python

Comment: Once you ran `json.load()` successfully,  you don't have a JSON file anymore, you have a Python data structure. There's no reason to ask about JSON in your question -- your problem and its solution would be 100% identical with *any other* tree of nested Python dictionaries, whether they were from JSON or not. It's like loading the a string from a HTTP request, trying to print it, getting a failure, and asking "Why can't I print a string I got from HTTP?" without checking whether the problem would also happen if the string came from a file / was hardcoded in the program / etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code will be helpful to get key value pair, to drill down such problem always open given json in json parser. and navigate to field of interest.

```
probeData= network['instances']['at-40-99-29']['probes']
for key,hostname in probeData.items():
    print(key)
    print(hostname)
    print(probeData[key]['hostname'])
```