# parsing/extracting nested JSON data with Python under Conditions

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to extract/parse the values from specifics in a JSON file that I did a post request.

Here is the JSON File. I am trying to get the values from the Key "AN". I want to be able to extract values such as "**shannoncampbell_znyq1**", "**katiekapprelmac**", etc. such that the values 
 from the second row **does not** equal to the number zero. For example, since the second row values (the for this row is **T7**) of **katiekapprelmac** does not equal to zero, my code should spit that out (**katiekapprelmac** should be the output). However it does not.

**JSON File:**

```
{
"id": "jsonrpc",
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"result": {
    "result": [
        {
            "AccountId": 697429,
            "Flags": [
                "AutoDeployed"
            ],
            "PartnerId": 287562,
            "Settings": [
                {
                    "AN": "shannoncampbell_znyq1"
                },
                {
                    "T7": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "AccountId": 725177,
            "Flags": null,
            "PartnerId": 287562,
            "Settings": [
                {
                    "AN": "katiekapprelmac"
                },
                {
                    "T7": "5"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "AccountId": 689130,
            "Flags": [
                "AutoDeployed"
            ],
            "PartnerId": 287562,
            "Settings": [
                {
                    "AN": "sara-pc_wpv7h"
                },
                {
                    "T7": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "AccountId": 697531,
            "Flags": null,
            "PartnerId": 287562,
            "Settings": [
                {
                    "AN": "kaelaweeksmac"
                },
                {
                    "T7": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "AccountId": 615877,
            "Flags": null,
            "PartnerId": 249098,
            "Settings": [
                {
                    "AN": "elenimacbookpro"
                },
                {
                    "T7": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "AccountId": 700661,
            "Flags": null,
            "PartnerId": 287562,
            "Settings": [
                {
                    "AN": "sethnickersonmac"
                },
                {
                    "T7": "0"
                }
            ]
        },
```

**Here is my python code:**

```
response2 = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload2, headers=headers)

j = json.loads(response2.text) 


def find_all(item, level):
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        for k in item:
            (find_all(item[k], level+1))
    else:
        print(item)


def find_only(item, level):
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        for k in item:
            (find_only(item[k], level+1))


for each in j['result']['result']:
    if (find_only(each['Settings'][1], 0)) != json.loads("0"):
        find_all(each['Settings'][0], 0)
```

Instead, I get all the keys in the output. I get the following:

```
shannoncampbell_znyq1
katiekapprelmac
sara-pc_wpv7h
kaelaweeksmac
elenimacbookpro
sethnickersonmac
```

Rather than just **katiekapprelmac**

**Please help. Thanks**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [recursive iteration through nested json for specific key in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028979/recursive-iteration-through-nested-json-for-specific-key-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code:

```
for each in j['result']['result']:
if (find_only(each['Settings'][1], 0)) != json.loads("0"):
    find_all(each['Settings'][0], 0)
```

I actually see, your condition is always `True`, as you are not returning anything in `find_only()`.

I don't know, why you are using level and so many recursive function. Although it's easy to extract result as per your data posted. please find below code.

```
response2 = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload2, headers=headers)
j = json.loads(response2.text)
for each in j['result']['result']:
if each['Settings'][1]['T7'] not in ["0", 0]:
    print(each['Settings'][0]['AN'])
```

If your response data is little complex then please post for exact solution.

If you have multiple key name then please look at below code:

```
response2 = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload2, headers=headers)
j = json.loads(response2.text)

def find_all(item):
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        for k in item:
            return item[k]
    # If item is non dict and you want to return this as well on `True`.
    # Uncomment below commented lines.
    # else:
    #     item
def find_only(item):
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        for k in item:
            return item[k]

for each in j['result']['result']:
    if (find_only(each['Settings'][1])) != str(json.loads("0")):
        print(find_all(each['Settings'][0]))
```

Comment: thank you for your response. What should be changed? thanks

Comment: Edited, hope you will get answer or some idea. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 1):

jsonpath-ng can help you with this.

```
from jsonpath_ng.ext import parse

found = parse(f"$..Settings").find(data)
if found:
    for i in found:
        if ''.join(i.value[1].values()) != '0':
            print(i.value[0]['AN'])
```