# How to loop for values in JsonStore kivy application?

Tags: python, kivy, jsonstore

I've been struggling to find a way to iterate through a certain set of values in multiple objects using the JsonStore module. My code:

```
class MainApp(App):

    def build(self): # build() returns an instance
        self.store = JsonStore("streak.json") # file that stores the streaks:


        return presentation

    def check_streak(self, instance):



        for value in self.store.find('delta'):

            if value > time.time():
                print("early")

            if value == time.time():
                print("on time")

            if value < time.time():
                print("late")
```

This function is connected to different buttons that are displayed on the page:

```
def display_btn(self):
        # display the names of the streaks in a list on PageTwo
        for key in self.store:
            streak_button = Button(text=key, on_press=self.check_streak)
            self.root.screen_two.ids.streak_zone.add_widget(streak_button)
```

When I use the check_streak I get `TypeError: find() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

What's inside the json file:

```
{"first": {"action": "first", "action_num": "1", "seconds": 60, "score": 0, "delta": 1555714261.0438898}, "second": {"action": "second", "action_num": "2", "seconds": 120, "score": 0, "delta": 1555879741.894656}}
```

Notice that every object starts with its name, in this case, "first" and "second". I want to be able to iterate through every objects "delta" key and get its value. Once I get the value of that objects 'delta' I will then compare it to the current time.

I have been referred to a question that involves generating ids but I don't see how that is related to my problem. Although I think a generator is good for creating random numbers, The data I'm working with isn't random. If using a generator is the only way to do what I'm trying to do could someone please explain to me how I could use it in my code?

The answers I have previously received don't account for the fact that I want the "delta" values to still be attached to the object rather than just listing them.

Comment: From the documentation, it looks like `self.store.find` expects one or more keyword arguments, probably something like `for value in self.store.find(delta='somevalue')`. This is also what the error means: the function didn't expect a positional argument at all.

Comment: Create a new question does not depend on the answers you have received, if it is the same question is a duplicate, and create new publications with the same question is considered noise here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## How to use [recursive iteration through nested json for specific key in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028979/recursive-iteration-through-nested-json-for-specific-key-in-python/39016088#39016088)

The following example does not use `JsonStore`. It is using `json.load` to load JSON objects.

### Snippets

```
import json
...
    def check_streak(self, *args):
        with open("streak.json", "r") as read_file:
            data = json.load(read_file)

            for honey in item_generator(data, 'delta'):
                print(f"honey={honey}")
                print(f"type(honey)={type(honey)}")

                if honey > time.time():
                    print("early")  # test

                if honey == time.time():
                    print("on time")

                if honey < time.time():
                    print("late")
```

## Note

The `store.find(key='value')` function cannot be used because `delta` is not fixed or constant. It is not like `name='kivy'`.

Comment: Thank you! This along with the already answered question helped. Sorry for creating a duplicate question, I just didn't understand the generator code for a while.