# How to find a key in a dictionary regardless of where it is? - Python

Tags: python, json

Okay so I'm trying to get all the keys named ['species'] in the following API call from PokeAPI: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/evolution-chain/140/

I'm not very good with JSON and since the data isn't always structured on the same list indexes, for example with this other call: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/133/ I'm not entirely sure how to get *all* keys named "species" as a list in the return of my function.

I can iterate through it just fine with the following code:

the response variable down below is just the apicall I linked above.

```
        response = requests.get(self.species_url + str(self.newspeciesid))
        testdata = response.json()
        evochainstest = testdata['evolution_chain']['url']
        chainsreq = requests.get(evochainstest)
        chainsreqjson = chainsreq.json()
        lengthofev = len(chainsreqjson['chain']['evolves_to'])
        
        list = []
        i = 0
        while(i < lengthofev):
            chainsreqparse = chainsreqjson['chain']['evolves_to'][i]['species']['name']
            list.append(chainsreqparse)
            i = i + 1
```

Is there a way to check for the name of a key in the entire dictionary, regardless of where it is and return it as a list? I'd greatly appreciate it! I have most of the webapp ready and while I get most evolutions, I am missing around 20 because of this. :(

****----- UPDATE to Fireshadow52's comment****

While I assume the answer given from him works, I'm not entirely sure how to apply it to my code

```
    def test_two(self):

        response = requests.get(self.species_url + str(self.newspeciesid))
        content = response.json()
        allids = content['id']
        allevochains = requests.get(self.base_url + str(allids))
        allevochainsjson = allevochains.json()
        

        if isinstance(allevochainsjson, dict):
            key = 'species'
            for k, v in allevochainsjson.items():
                if k == "species":
                    yield v
                else:
                    yield from allevochainsjson(v, key)
        elif isinstance(allevochainsjson, list):
            for item in allevochainsjson:
                yield from allevochainsjson(item, key)
```

This is what I have now and it returns it as a <generator object PokeSearch.test_two at 0x0000020E306910E0> object, did I do something wrong?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028979/how-to-recursively-find-specific-key-in-nested-json)

Comment: Hmm, while I guess that would be a solution, I'm not entirely sure how to apply it to my code. I got something like this going replacing some of the values on the answers, I'll update my question so its more visible.

Comment: The `item_generator()` function in that answer is exactly that: a generator of the items you're looking for. You just pass your dictionary and the key you're looking for, and it will yield the values you're after. E.g. `yield from item_generator(allevochainsjson, 'species')`