# JSON Parsing with Python3.6 giving issue

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to extract the particular key's value from the json Array in a file. I am trying to extrcat the value from the keys where ever the key is available anywhere in the json array. Here is the code that I am using:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
import json        
def bar(somejson, key):
    def val(node):
        # Searches for the next Element Node containing Value
        e = node.nextSibling
        while e and e.nodeType != e.ELEMENT_NODE:
            e = e.nextSibling
        return (e.getElementsByTagName('string')[0].firstChild.nodeValue if e 
                else None)
    # parse the JSON as XML
    foo_dom = parseString(xmlrpclib.dumps((json.loads(somejson),)))
    # and then search all the name tags which are P1's
    # and use the val user function to get the value
    return [val(node) for node in foo_dom.getElementsByTagName('name') 
            if node.firstChild.nodeValue in key]
```

This I have got from the question: [How can I use python finding particular json value by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048948/how-can-i-use-python-finding-particular-json-value-by-key)
Now I am getting any error at the `xmlrpclib`. I am not getting why it is coming. I tried to get the package using `pip` but no such package is available for installation.
Kindly suggest me what should I do? The example of data is same as in the question link mentioned above.

Comment: Are you importing the `xmlrpclib` library? By the way this library is available on [`PyPi`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmlrpclib)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri How I can install it? I tried to setup but could not or is there a way to use it in my program. Please help.

Comment: @JafferWilson did you see my answer? It's still part of the standard library.

Comment: @Vallentin oop I forgot to refresh. Ok I just need to use it using import... I am new to python3 a bit. so was not knowing.

Comment: You may find my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41777880/functions-that-help-to-understand-jsondict-structure) helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3 the `xmlrpclib` library was renamed to `xmlrpc`. `dumps` is now located in `xmlrpc.client`. So to fix your problem either do:

```
import xmlrpc.client as xmlrpclib
```

or replace `xmlrpclib.dumps` with `xmlrpc.client.dumps` and `import xmlrpc.client`.

Comment: Thank you this helps a lot..:)