# How to extract items within nested lists containing nested dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have a nested item list containing complicated nested dictionaries as shown:

```
y = [
{
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 304,
    "per_page": "1",
    "total": 304
},
[
    {
        "adminregion": {
            "id": "",
            "value": ""
        },
        "capitalCity": "Oranjestad",
        "id": "ABW",
        "incomeLevel": {
            "id": "HIC",
            "value": "High income"
        },
        "iso2Code": "AW",
        "latitude": "12.5167",
        "lendingType": {
            "id": "LNX",
            "value": "Not classified"
        },
        "longitude": "-70.0167",
        "name": "Aruba",
        "region": {
            "id": "LCN",
            "value": "Latin America & Caribbean "
        }
    }
]]
```

and I am trying to extract the "id" values and store them somewhere in a database.
What I've tried so far is (not successful):

```
print([i['id'] for i in y[1]])
```

and:

```
 for i in y[1]:
    for j in i:
        print(j)
```

but no luck 
Thanks a million..

Comment: With my code in the linked question you can do `for k, v in find_key(y, 'id'): print(k, v)` to get the paths to all `'id'` keys, with their values. With the given data the result is `[1, 0, 'adminregion', 'id'], [1, 0, 'id'] ABW, [1, 0, 'incomeLevel', 'id'] HIC, [1, 0, 'lendingType', 'id'] LNX, [1, 0, 'region', 'id'] LCN`

Comment: did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14059645/2706419

Comment: Yes that worked out thanks PM 2Ring and naveen marri