# How to check if key is present in nested list in json?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file where each object looks like the following example:

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": 1569177699,
    "attachments": [

    ],
    "data": [
       {
         "post": "\u00f0\u009f\u0096\u00a4\u00f0\u009f\u0092\u0099"
       },
       {
         "update_timestamp": 1569177699
       }
    ],
    "title": "firstName LastName"
  }
]
```

I want to check if, there is the key `post`, nested within the key `data`. I wrote this, but it doesn't work:

```
 posts = json.loads(open(file).read())
 for post in posts:
     if 'data' in post:
        if 'post' in post['data']
            print post['data']['post']
```

Comment: What symptom are you getting when you run your code?

Comment: `post['data']` is a list you need to iterate over it to get the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution. I see from your sample data that `post["data"]` is a `list`, so the program should iterate over it:

```
posts = json.loads(open(file).read())
    for post in posts:
        if 'data' in post:
            #THIS IS THE NEW LINE to iterate list
            for d in post["data"]:
                if 'post' in d:
                    print d['post']
```

Comment: You are welcome, it was not a problem at all. Im glad I could be of assistance and its nice to hear thanks when you help somebody on this days

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
posts = json.loads(open(file).read())
for data in posts:
    for key, value in data.items():
        if key == 'data':
            for item in value:
                if 'post' in item:
                    print(key, item['post'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer this works!

[Elegant way to check if a nested key exists in a python dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43491287/elegant-way-to-check-if-a-nested-key-exists-in-a-python-dict/43492603)

```
def keys_exists(element, *keys):
    '''
    Check if *keys (nested) exists in `element` (dict).
    '''
    if not isinstance(element, dict):
        raise AttributeError('keys_exists() expects dict as first argument.')
    if len(keys) == 0:
        raise AttributeError('keys_exists() expects at least two arguments, one given.')

    _element = element
    for key in keys:
        try:
            _element = _element[key]
        except KeyError:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it generically by adapting [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14059645/355230) to the question [How to find a particular json value by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048948/how-to-find-a-particular-json-value-by-key).

It's generic in the sense that it doesn't care much about the details of how the JSON data is structured, it just checks every dictionary it finds inside it.

```
import json

def find_values(id, json_file):
    results = []

    def _decode_dict(a_dict):
        try:
            results.append(a_dict[id])
        except KeyError:
            pass
        return a_dict

    json.load(json_file, object_hook=_decode_dict)  # Return value ignored.
    return len(results) > 0  # If there are any results, id was found.

with open('find_key_test.json', 'r') as json_file:
    print(find_values('post', json_file)) # -> True
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the following:

```
posts = json.loads(open(file).read())

for post in posts:
    if 'data' in post:
        for data in post['data']:
            if 'post' in data:
                print(data['post'])
```