# How to find key by name in json-query?

Tags: javascript

I have JSON object:

```
{
  "type": "...",
  "start": 0,
  "end": 93,
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "...",
      "start": 0,
      "end": 93,
      "more": {
        "type": "...",
        "start": 0,
        "__FOO__": true,
        "end": 93,
```

I want to get `__FOO__` property from that object using [json-query](https://github.com/auditassistant/json-query).

The problem is `__FOO__` can be anywhere in the object. I mean deep inside or at the root. also the object structure can be change (array may be object or even not exist).

So I tried to get this property using this syntax but it doesn't work. What is the syntax that can find me `__FOO__`?

```
const data = require("./data.json");

const jsonQuery = require("json-query");

const x = jsonQuery("[__FOO__]", { data });

console.log(x);
```

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-hoover-pvtvj?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find a particular json value by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048948/how-to-find-a-particular-json-value-by-key)

Comment: no. I the answer is in Pyton. I using json-query with JavaScript

Comment: @ra.design You link to a python answer and an answer that doesn't use json-query.

Comment: Sorry about that! I think you need to loop through all keys of the given JSON with `for (var key in json)`.

Comment: and what are you looking for? `body`? `expression`? `xxx`? `property`? `arguments`?

Answer (score 1):

I think `"items[**][__FOO__!=null]"` seems to work. It returns the object containing `__FOO__`, not the value of `__FOO__` itself.

Comment: Well I'm not sure what to tell ya, I tested it on the code you posted and it works for me.