# How can I extract URLs from a one line JSON text file using regex?

Tags: python, json

I've been trying to work this out, but I can only seem to get one URL to be exported to the output file.

The code I am currently using is...

```
import glob, re

with open('urls.txt', 'a') as output:
    for file in glob.glob('json.txt'):
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                pattern = r"(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])"
                find = re.findall(pattern, line)
                if find:
                    try:
                        output.write(str(find[0]))
                    except UnicodeEncodeError:
                        pass
```

I've tested the Regex code and it's able to match all the URLs, just won't output them all to a file.

The file I've been trying to extract URLs from contains the following (indented for legibility):

```
{
    "items": [{
        "schema": "Event",
        "source_id": "99558834",
        "event_id": "7103414757044987314",
        "start_time": "2022-05-30T06:37:10Z",
        "end_time": "2022-05-30T06:37:24Z",
        "event_type": "motion",
        "source_type": null,
        "duration_ms": 14400,
        "session_duration": 14000,
        "state": "timed_out",
        "had_subscription": true,
        "is_favorite": false,
        "recording_status": "ready",
        "cv": {
            "person_detected": true,
            "stream_broken": false,
            "detection_type": "human",
            "cv_triggers": null,
            "detection_types": [{
                "detection_type": "human",
                "verified_timestamps": [1653892632153]
            }]
        },
        "properties": {
            "is_alexa": false,
            "is_sidewalk": false,
            "is_autoreply": false
        },
        "origin": null,
        "error_message": null,
        "updated_at": "2022-05-30T06:37:28.958Z",
        "visualizations": {
            "cloud_media_visualization": {
                "schema": "CloudMediaVisualization",
                "media": [{
                    "schema": "Media",
                    "url": "https://filestore-086356611853-us-west-2-prod-data.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/8cbfaccd-9b1a-458b-88b9-5d12976f4293.mp4?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjECcaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQCd%2FiqSm%2BFneYZ1sRxM1yNyc3Cr8bVV92jQRo6k%2B4A7pwIhAO4ufSc2Ol8wevIQBjAUZz%2B7%2B%2FZrSgGpNtDhBH6hWlikKtIECB8QABoMNzM0NDEwMjU5OTMxIgyxJGK4nrZlY0QIGNQqrwTjz9YEN9G7vRk%2Bu9qUDpVIrwzd2jNXuCJ92K%2BHVCpSQb8wFqg6%2Bh521Ukotxvl9HXThrBDfgK4madk3%2FJ1Gynn3M%2BZ7MJnpLu0uA9tUperBazYvaNzPgFWBS2kWSUObSO5Jfwn6L9VoB4D%2F%2FHvOJa5pmDVXFc2s4hSkyxrXfw7W5OoBxdjKPU5TcdamZy7uJgLElZec%2F7PO99okNwIYQDS0RKKpcdZs3VbBiceXeb8ApDIcDWonMrnmz18Gz9wG%2B6ERrM6Av31UXID875c6DqfbqxCxpGpVXBlSy6jQENn%2Bl%2Bc5xewwhY4mTq90CcCZXnebCyoqkr2mt0S3lkZSBxdOI8qnoojCmg7yy%2BFII63h4NKQbEbhm2u1u%2Fb1Ar5UfD4wHzsalhZp83Xej5Lsg0uXvpRCaYoR6mQgvnmVmS1bIFe0StzTHhJHViwEb4XbSK3u5Z%2FniVcBbVKsidNN9%2FA33okRPz7FMjpEaOB3lsbeTpmBcC86GlnwFxarYEvWY6eN7uxE0pzuK2asYgat5JqaNj%2FbRMaW1hi7ivGAj9uFZjMteTdrsNAq6lbLaiL1POhB98D0eJumvA1xu%2FbxoE7VrW%2BikA2LOGwni5EAZ9LIzywxOHx9a5iiC%2BAFjwUGEzswdmzo0mAq0llNp1twfG5Bn47DHrUfF3NubD3aCA01mQ%2FSbKKBv%2BnMD6FK2yo9f8y2Ol%2F12%2FRLQMZbkA6i7TpaE7HNvj3ElWgwUp8OddeMPaD1ZQGOqgB4vDMx4xDOedv0RjNjZikdYtR2dHU3V4K9Ls2qUqF6NJ%2FrbvgwL1s4%2Bm3ZMeOUmLfJDMazkWg8jSNRfKBWFParp2R0%2Fg8TDUEOecwrbmN7cKG3vtnOpZIcFCD46bWvKm9czEun5zbNg6Q1rCLob5RTkEG6H0A729wvomQRldlb6QBtwAC0B7mfnRGgNZrEN3z0SSauZJS3mabSGhxwc0Oem6mFKK6s9Qh&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220530T225422Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Credential=ASIA2V7SDHXNTJG3BKDZ%2F20220530%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=b42e734ab24ce1c8057038a171c995326de1a8cf219810c33c0d0883e2ea38b2",
                    "custom_metadata": null,
                    "is_e2ee": false,
                    "manifest_id": null,
                    "file_type": "VIDEO",
                    "file_family": "VIDEO",
                    "preroll_duration_ms": 0,
                    "playback_duration": 14000,
                    "source": "Apsara"
                }, {
                    "schema": "Media",
                    "url": "https://filestore-086356611853-us-west-2-prod-data.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/b22b3c85-5de3-4e91-92b5-d91db479df55.mp4?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjECcaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQCd%2FiqSm%2BFneYZ1sRxM1yNyc3Cr8bVV92jQRo6k%2B4A7pwIhAO4ufSc2Ol8wevIQBjAUZz%2B7%2B%2FZrSgGpNtDhBH6hWlikKtIECB8QABoMNzM0NDEwMjU5OTMxIgyxJGK4nrZlY0QIGNQqrwTjz9YEN9G7vRk%2Bu9qUDpVIrwzd2jNXuCJ92K%2BHVCpSQb8wFqg6%2Bh521Ukotxvl9HXThrBDfgK4madk3%2FJ1Gynn3M%2BZ7MJnpLu0uA9tUperBazYvaNzPgFWBS2kWSUObSO5Jfwn6L9VoB4D%2F%2FHvOJa5pmDVXFc2s4hSkyxrXfw7W5OoBxdjKPU5TcdamZy7uJgLElZec%2F7PO99okNwIYQDS0RKKpcdZs3VbBiceXeb8ApDIcDWonMrnmz18Gz9wG%2B6ERrM6Av31UXID875c6DqfbqxCxpGpVXBlSy6jQENn%2Bl%2Bc5xewwhY4mTq90CcCZXnebCyoqkr2mt0S3lkZSBxdOI8qnoojCmg7yy%2BFII63h4NKQbEbhm2u1u%2Fb1Ar5UfD4wHzsalhZp83Xej5Lsg0uXvpRCaYoR6mQgvnmVmS1bIFe0StzTHhJHViwEb4XbSK3u5Z%2FniVcBbVKsidNN9%2FA33okRPz7FMjpEaOB3lsbeTpmBcC86GlnwFxarYEvWY6eN7uxE0pzuK2asYgat5JqaNj%2FbRMaW1hi7ivGAj9uFZjMteTdrsNAq6lbLaiL1POhB98D0eJumvA1xu%2FbxoE7VrW%2BikA2LOGwni5EAZ9LIzywxOHx9a5iiC%2BAFjwUGEzswdmzo0mAq0llNp1twfG5Bn47DHrUfF3NubD3aCA01mQ%2FSbKKBv%2BnMD6FK2yo9f8y2Ol%2F12%2FRLQMZbkA6i7TpaE7HNvj3ElWgwUp8OddeMPaD1ZQGOqgB4vDMx4xDOedv0RjNjZikdYtR2dHU3V4K9Ls2qUqF6NJ%2FrbvgwL1s4%2Bm3ZMeOUmLfJDMazkWg8jSNRfKBWFParp2R0%2Fg8TDUEOecwrbmN7cKG3vtnOpZIcFCD46bWvKm9czEun5zbNg6Q1rCLob5RTkEG6H0A729wvomQRldlb6QBtwAC0B7mfnRGgNZrEN3z0SSauZJS3mabSGhxwc0Oem6mFKK6s9Qh&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220530T225422Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Credential=ASIA2V7SDHXNTJG3BKDZ%2F20220530%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=7724f211de257f1f13fb585158f0f241e47daa1f1f67a3e48527e45883889a8b",
                    "custom_metadata": null,
                    "is_e2ee": false,
                    "manifest_id": null,
                    "file_type": "LQ_VIDEO",
                    "file_family": "LQ_VIDEO",
                    "preroll_duration_ms": 0,
                    "playback_duration": 14400,
                    "source": "Apsara"
                }, {
                    "schema": "Media",
                    "url": "https://filestore-086356611853-us-west-2-prod-data.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/564fb900-0d78-4521-8a3d-b760fff7ee8d.iframe?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjECcaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQCd%2FiqSm%2BFneYZ1sRxM1yNyc3Cr8bVV92jQRo6k%2B4A7pwIhAO4ufSc2Ol8wevIQBjAUZz%2B7%2B%2FZrSgGpNtDhBH6hWlikKtIECB8QABoMNzM0NDEwMjU5OTMxIgyxJGK4nrZlY0QIGNQqrwTjz9YEN9G7vRk%2Bu9qUDpVIrwzd2jNXuCJ92K%2BHVCpSQb8wFqg6%2Bh521Ukotxvl9HXThrBDfgK4madk3%2FJ1Gynn3M%2BZ7MJnpLu0uA9tUperBazYvaNzPgFWBS2kWSUObSO5Jfwn6L9VoB4D%2F%2FHvOJa5pmDVXFc2s4hSkyxrXfw7W5OoBxdjKPU5TcdamZy7uJgLElZec%2F7PO99okNwIYQDS0RKKpcdZs3VbBiceXeb8ApDIcDWonMrnmz18Gz9wG%2B6ERrM6Av31UXID875c6DqfbqxCxpGpVXBlSy6jQENn%2Bl%2Bc5xewwhY4mTq90CcCZXnebCyoqkr2mt0S3lkZSBxdOI8qnoojCmg7yy%2BFII63h4NKQbEbhm2u1u%2Fb1Ar5UfD4wHzsalhZp83Xej5Lsg0uXvpRCaYoR6mQgvnmVmS1bIFe0StzTHhJHViwEb4XbSK3u5Z%2FniVcBbVKsidNN9%2FA33okRPz7FMjpEaOB3lsbeTpmBcC86GlnwFxarYEvWY6eN7uxE0pzuK2asYgat5JqaNj%2FbRMaW1hi7ivGAj9uFZjMteTdrsNAq6lbLaiL1POhB98D0eJumvA1xu%2FbxoE7VrW%2BikA2LOGwni5EAZ9LIzywxOHx9a5iiC%2BAFjwUGEzswdmzo0mAq0llNp1twfG5Bn47DHrUfF3NubD3aCA01mQ%2FSbKKBv%2BnMD6FK2yo9f8y2Ol%2F12%2FRLQMZbkA6i7TpaE7HNvj3ElWgwUp8OddeMPaD1ZQGOqgB4vDMx4xDOedv0RjNjZikdYtR2dHU3V4K9Ls2qUqF6NJ%2FrbvgwL1s4%2Bm3ZMeOUmLfJDMazkWg8jSNRfKBWFParp2R0%2Fg8TDUEOecwrbmN7cKG3vtnOpZIcFCD46bWvKm9czEun5zbNg6Q1rCLob5RTkEG6H0A729wvomQRldlb6QBtwAC0B7mfnRGgNZrEN3z0SSauZJS3mabSGhxwc0Oem6mFKK6s9Qh&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220530T225422Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Credential=ASIA2V7SDHXNTJG3BKDZ%2F20220530%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=8ccd9823cd6d2fe0e386b843a700bd05cc3a694c6986a55b75c797cbf846b7c6",
                    "custom_metadata": null,
                    "is_e2ee": false,
                    "manifest_id": null,
                    "file_type": "THUMBNAIL",
                    "file_family": "THUMBNAIL",
                    "preroll_duration_ms": 0,
                    "playback_duration": 14000,
                    "source": "Apsara"
                }]
            },
            "local_media_visualization": {
                "schema": "LocalMediaVisualization",
                "media": []
            },
            "radar_visualization": null,
            "single_coordinate_visualization": null,
            "map_visualization": null
        },
        "device": {
            "id": 99558834,
            "description": "Front",
            "type": "cocoa_camera"
        },
        "owner_id": "71616327"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Why do you parse json with regex? Use `json` module.

Comment: The whole point of JSON is that it's easily parsable by many languages. Don't treat it as a string, rather treat it as an object by parsing it as an object/dictionary.

Comment: This isn't valid json. If that's intentional, maybe that's why OP has resorted to a regex

Comment: This is valid JSON. The OP only forgot to paste the closing brackets because they copied it up until the end of the first of multiple items. @Magicskit You are not supposed to use regex for this. Use the `json` module, as Andrej said.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be easier to make the data you have valid JSON and then use the `object_hook` parameter that [`json.loads()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) supports. For more details see my answer to [How to find a particular JSON value by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14059645/355230).

Here's how to apply it your data:

```
import json

def find_values(id, json_repr):
    results = []

    def _decode_dict(a_dict):
        try:
            results.append(a_dict[id])
        except KeyError:
            pass
        return a_dict

    json.loads(json_repr, object_hook=_decode_dict) # Return value ignored.
    return results

with open('filename.json') as file:
    jstr = file.read()

json_repr = jstr + ']}'  # Make jstr valid JSON.

results = find_values('url', json_repr)
print(f'{len(results)} URLs found')
for i, url in enumerate(results, start=1):
    print(f'{i}: {url}')
```

Output:

```
3 URLs found
1: https://filestore-086356611853-us-west-2-prod-data.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/8cbfaccd-9b1a-458b-88b9-5d12976f4293.mp4?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjECcaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQCd%2FiqSm%2BFneYZ1sRxM1yNyc3Cr8bVV92jQRo6k%2B4A7pwIhAO4ufSc2Ol8wevIQBjAUZz%2B7%2B%2FZrSgGpNtDhBH6hWlikKtIECB8QABoMNzM0NDEwMjU5OTMxIgyxJGK4nrZlY0QIGNQqrwTjz9YEN9G7vRk%2Bu9qUDpVIrwzd2jNXuCJ92K%2BHVCpSQb8wFqg6%2Bh521Ukotxvl9HXThrBDfgK4madk3%2FJ1Gynn3M%2BZ7MJnpLu0uA9tUperBazYvaNzPgFWBS2kWSUObSO5Jfwn6L9VoB4D%2F%2FHvOJa5pmDVXFc2s4hSkyxrXfw7W5OoBxdjKPU5TcdamZy7uJgLElZec%2F7PO99okNwIYQDS0RKKpcdZs3VbBiceXeb8ApDIcDWonMrnmz18Gz9wG%2B6ERrM6Av31UXID875c6DqfbqxCxpGpVXBlSy6jQENn%2Bl%2Bc5xewwhY4mTq90CcCZXnebCyoqkr2mt0S3lkZSBxdOI8qnoojCmg7yy%2BFII63h4NKQbEbhm2u1u%2Fb1Ar5UfD4wHzsalhZp83Xej5Lsg0uXvpRCaYoR6mQgvnmVmS1bIFe0StzTHhJHViwEb4XbSK3u5Z%2FniVcBbVKsidNN9%2FA33okRPz7FMjpEaOB3lsbeTpmBcC86GlnwFxarYEvWY6eN7uxE0pzuK2asYgat5JqaNj%2FbRMaW1hi7ivGAj9uFZjMteTdrsNAq6lbLaiL1POhB98D0eJumvA1xu%2FbxoE7VrW%2BikA2LOGwni5EAZ9LIzywxOHx9a5iiC%2BAFjwUGEzswdmzo0mAq0llNp1twfG5Bn47DHrUfF3NubD3aCA01mQ%2FSbKKBv%2BnMD6FK2yo9f8y2Ol%2F12%2FRLQMZbkA6i7TpaE7HNvj3ElWgwUp8OddeMPaD1ZQGOqgB4vDMx4xDOedv0RjNjZikdYtR2dHU3V4K9Ls2qUqF6NJ%2FrbvgwL1s4%2Bm3ZMeOUmLfJDMazkWg8jSNRfKBWFParp2R0%2Fg8TDUEOecwrbmN7cKG3vtnOpZIcFCD46bWvKm9czEun5zbNg6Q1rCLob5RTkEG6H0A729wvomQRldlb6QBtwAC0B7mfnRGgNZrEN3z0SSauZJS3mabSGhxwc0Oem6mFKK6s9Qh&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220530T225422Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Credential=ASIA2V7SDHXNTJG3BKDZ%2F20220530%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=b42e734ab24ce1c8057038a171c995326de1a8cf219810c33c0d0883e2ea38b2
2: https://filestore-086356611853-us-west-2-prod-data.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/b22b3c85-5de3-4e91-92b5-d91db479df55.mp4?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjECcaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQCd%2FiqSm%2BFneYZ1sRxM1yNyc3Cr8bVV92jQRo6k%2B4A7pwIhAO4ufSc2Ol8wevIQBjAUZz%2B7%2B%2FZrSgGpNtDhBH6hWlikKtIECB8QABoMNzM0NDEwMjU5OTMxIgyxJGK4nrZlY0QIGNQqrwTjz9YEN9G7vRk%2Bu9qUDpVIrwzd2jNXuCJ92K%2BHVCpSQb8wFqg6%2Bh521Ukotxvl9HXThrBDfgK4madk3%2FJ1Gynn3M%2BZ7MJnpLu0uA9tUperBazYvaNzPgFWBS2kWSUObSO5Jfwn6L9VoB4D%2F%2FHvOJa5pmDVXFc2s4hSkyxrXfw7W5OoBxdjKPU5TcdamZy7uJgLElZec%2F7PO99okNwIYQDS0RKKpcdZs3VbBiceXeb8ApDIcDWonMrnmz18Gz9wG%2B6ERrM6Av31UXID875c6DqfbqxCxpGpVXBlSy6jQENn%2Bl%2Bc5xewwhY4mTq90CcCZXnebCyoqkr2mt0S3lkZSBxdOI8qnoojCmg7yy%2BFII63h4NKQbEbhm2u1u%2Fb1Ar5UfD4wHzsalhZp83Xej5Lsg0uXvpRCaYoR6mQgvnmVmS1bIFe0StzTHhJHViwEb4XbSK3u5Z%2FniVcBbVKsidNN9%2FA33okRPz7FMjpEaOB3lsbeTpmBcC86GlnwFxarYEvWY6eN7uxE0pzuK2asYgat5JqaNj%2FbRMaW1hi7ivGAj9uFZjMteTdrsNAq6lbLaiL1POhB98D0eJumvA1xu%2FbxoE7VrW%2BikA2LOGwni5EAZ9LIzywxOHx9a5iiC%2BAFjwUGEzswdmzo0mAq0llNp1twfG5Bn47DHrUfF3NubD3aCA01mQ%2FSbKKBv%2BnMD6FK2yo9f8y2Ol%2F12%2FRLQMZbkA6i7TpaE7HNvj3ElWgwUp8OddeMPaD1ZQGOqgB4vDMx4xDOedv0RjNjZikdYtR2dHU3V4K9Ls2qUqF6NJ%2FrbvgwL1s4%2Bm3ZMeOUmLfJDMazkWg8jSNRfKBWFParp2R0%2Fg8TDUEOecwrbmN7cKG3vtnOpZIcFCD46bWvKm9czEun5zbNg6Q1rCLob5RTkEG6H0A729wvomQRldlb6QBtwAC0B7mfnRGgNZrEN3z0SSauZJS3mabSGhxwc0Oem6mFKK6s9Qh&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220530T225422Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Credential=ASIA2V7SDHXNTJG3BKDZ%2F20220530%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=7724f211de257f1f13fb585158f0f241e47daa1f1f67a3e48527e45883889a8b
3: https://filestore-086356611853-us-west-2-prod-data.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/564fb900-0d78-4521-8a3d-b760fff7ee8d.iframe?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjECcaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQCd%2FiqSm%2BFneYZ1sRxM1yNyc3Cr8bVV92jQRo6k%2B4A7pwIhAO4ufSc2Ol8wevIQBjAUZz%2B7%2B%2FZrSgGpNtDhBH6hWlikKtIECB8QABoMNzM0NDEwMjU5OTMxIgyxJGK4nrZlY0QIGNQqrwTjz9YEN9G7vRk%2Bu9qUDpVIrwzd2jNXuCJ92K%2BHVCpSQb8wFqg6%2Bh521Ukotxvl9HXThrBDfgK4madk3%2FJ1Gynn3M%2BZ7MJnpLu0uA9tUperBazYvaNzPgFWBS2kWSUObSO5Jfwn6L9VoB4D%2F%2FHvOJa5pmDVXFc2s4hSkyxrXfw7W5OoBxdjKPU5TcdamZy7uJgLElZec%2F7PO99okNwIYQDS0RKKpcdZs3VbBiceXeb8ApDIcDWonMrnmz18Gz9wG%2B6ERrM6Av31UXID875c6DqfbqxCxpGpVXBlSy6jQENn%2Bl%2Bc5xewwhY4mTq90CcCZXnebCyoqkr2mt0S3lkZSBxdOI8qnoojCmg7yy%2BFII63h4NKQbEbhm2u1u%2Fb1Ar5UfD4wHzsalhZp83Xej5Lsg0uXvpRCaYoR6mQgvnmVmS1bIFe0StzTHhJHViwEb4XbSK3u5Z%2FniVcBbVKsidNN9%2FA33okRPz7FMjpEaOB3lsbeTpmBcC86GlnwFxarYEvWY6eN7uxE0pzuK2asYgat5JqaNj%2FbRMaW1hi7ivGAj9uFZjMteTdrsNAq6lbLaiL1POhB98D0eJumvA1xu%2FbxoE7VrW%2BikA2LOGwni5EAZ9LIzywxOHx9a5iiC%2BAFjwUGEzswdmzo0mAq0llNp1twfG5Bn47DHrUfF3NubD3aCA01mQ%2FSbKKBv%2BnMD6FK2yo9f8y2Ol%2F12%2FRLQMZbkA6i7TpaE7HNvj3ElWgwUp8OddeMPaD1ZQGOqgB4vDMx4xDOedv0RjNjZikdYtR2dHU3V4K9Ls2qUqF6NJ%2FrbvgwL1s4%2Bm3ZMeOUmLfJDMazkWg8jSNRfKBWFParp2R0%2Fg8TDUEOecwrbmN7cKG3vtnOpZIcFCD46bWvKm9czEun5zbNg6Q1rCLob5RTkEG6H0A729wvomQRldlb6QBtwAC0B7mfnRGgNZrEN3z0SSauZJS3mabSGhxwc0Oem6mFKK6s9Qh&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220530T225422Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Credential=ASIA2V7SDHXNTJG3BKDZ%2F20220530%2Fus-west-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=8ccd9823cd6d2fe0e386b843a700bd05cc3a694c6986a55b75c797cbf846b7c6
```

Comment: How would you be able to implement pulling data from a file?

Comment: If the JSON-like, but incomplete/invalid data was in a file, it would have to be read into memory as plain text before fixing it. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, there are better ways to parse/read json, but given your code, it could do what you want with a small tweak.

```
import glob, re

with open('urls.txt', 'a') as output:
    for file in glob.glob('json.txt'):
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                pattern = r"(http|ftp|https):\/\/([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])"
                find = re.findall(pattern, line)
                if find:
                    try:
                        for result in find:
                            output.write(str(result) + "\n")
                    except UnicodeEncodeError:
                        pass
```

You have only asked to output the first of the matched results (`find[0]`). You want to get all of them, so loop through them then output them.