# dump json into yaml

Tags: python, json, encoding, yaml

I got a `.json` file (named it `meta.json`) like this:

```
{
    "main": {
        "title": "今日は雨が降って",
        "description": "今日は雨が降って"
    }
}
```

I would like to convert it to a `.yaml`  file (named it `meta.yaml`) like :

```
title: "今日は雨が降って"
description: "今日は雨が降って"
```

What I have done was :

```
import simplejson as json
import pyyaml

f = open('meta.json', 'r')
jsonData = json.load(f)
f.close()

ff = open('meta.yaml', 'w+')
yamlData = {'title':'', 'description':''}
yamlData['title'] = jsonData['main']['title']
yamlData['description'] = jsonData['main']['description']
yaml.dump(yamlData, ff)
# So you can  see that what I need is the value of meta.json
```

But sadly, what I got is following:

```
{description: "\u4ECA\u65E5\u306F\u96E8\u304C\u964D\u3063\u3066", title: "\u4ECA\u65E5\
\u306F\u96E8\u304C\u964D\u3063"}
```

Why?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`pyyaml.dump()` has an `allow_unicode` option that defaults to `None` (all non-ASCII characters in the output are escaped). If `allow_unicode=True`, then it writes raw Unicode strings.

```py
yaml.dump(data, ff, allow_unicode=True)
```

#### Bonus

You can dump JSON without encoding as follows:

```py
json.dump(data, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Comment: what's the bonus do?

Comment: question is about yaml, bonus is about json. both dumps none-ascii chars without encoding.

Answer (score 20):

This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import json
import yaml

print(yaml.dump(json.load(open(sys.argv[1])), default_flow_style=False))
```

So what we are doing is:

1. load json file through json.loads
2. json loads in unicode format - convert that to string by json.dump
3. load the yaml through yaml.load
4. dump the same in a file through yaml.dump - default_flow_style - True displays data inline, False doesn't do inline - so you have dumpable data ready.

Takes care of unicode as per [How to get string objects instead of Unicode from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956867/how-to-get-string-objects-instead-of-unicode-ones-from-json-in-python)

Comment: Since loaded json and yaml files both work with python dicts internally, simpy doing `print(yaml.dump(json.load(open(sys.argv[1]))))` does the same thing. Works for python 3.

Comment: How do you get this to actually indent lists though? Especially after they follow a key.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [1]: import json, yaml

In [2]: with open('test.json') as js:
   ...:     data = json.load(js)[u'main']
   ...:     

In [3]: with open('test.yaml', 'w') as yml:
   ...:     yaml.dump(data, yml, allow_unicode=True)
   ...:     

In [4]: ! cat test.yaml
{!!python/unicode 'description': 今日は雨が降って, !!python/unicode 'title': 今日は雨が降って}

In [5]: with open('test.yaml', 'w') as yml:
   ...:     yaml.safe_dump(data, yml, allow_unicode=True)
   ...:     

In [6]: ! cat test.yaml
{description: 今日は雨が降って, title: 今日は雨が降って}
```

Answer (score 3):

I do simply:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import json
import yaml

yaml.safe_dump(json.load(sys.stdin), sys.stdout, default_flow_style=False)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Using this with `yaml.safe_dump(...)` instead prevents the addition of the python unicode tags, but this converted nicely into a oneliner for me!

Comment: You are right. Since then there is `safe_dump`. :-) I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is correct.
The "\u...." strings are unicode representation of your Japanese?  string. When you decode and use it with proper encoding, it should display fine wherever you use it. eg a webpage.

See the equality of data inspite of different representation as string :

```
>>> import json
>>> j = '{    "main": {        "title": "今日は雨が降って",        "description": "今日は雨が降って"    }}'
>>> s = json.loads(j)
>>> t = json.dumps(s)
>>> j
'{    "main": {        "title": "\xe4\xbb\x8a\xe6\x97\xa5\xe3\x81\xaf\xe9\x9b\xa8\xe3\x81\x8c\xe9\x99\x8d\xe3\x81\xa3\xe3\x81\xa6",        "description": "\xe4\xbb\x8a\xe6\x97\xa5\xe3\x81\xaf\xe9\x9b\xa8\xe3\x81\x8c\xe9\x99\x8d\xe3\x81\xa3\xe3\x81\xa6"    }}'
>>> t
'{"main": {"description": "\\u4eca\\u65e5\\u306f\\u96e8\\u304c\\u964d\\u3063\\u3066", "title": "\\u4eca\\u65e5\\u306f\\u96e8\\u304c\\u964d\\u3063\\u3066"}}'
>>> s == json.loads(t)
True
```