# Export postgres table to yaml file

Tags: python, django, psql

I am working in django and trying to figure out how to export a table i have in my database to a yaml file, but cant find the solution to it..probably some simple change..
Right now i have a written a bash to export my customer table to a CSV file that works fine:

**export_customer.sh**

```
echo "Enter the directory path to save the file"
read path_to_save
file_name="myFile.csv"

psql --dbname=mydb --host=localhost --username=mydb -c "COPY
(
select name, id from customers
) to stdout DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER" > "${path_to_save}/${file_name}"
```

My customer table look something like this:

```
id             name
-------------------
 1             xxxxx
 2             yyyyy
```

Does anyone now how to export this into a yaml file instead?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bit roundabout but if you don't care about performance, you can export your table to a JSON and then convert the JSON to a yaml.

1. Table to JSON: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90482/export-postgres-table-as-json
2. JSON to yaml: [dump json into yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941996/dump-json-into-yaml)

Comment: Yes to go that way seems easy, how thought about it before, but were hoping to find a more direct way to solve it. Thx anyway Aziz