# How to prevent Unicode representation for Latin1 characters?

Tags: python, json, unicode, flask, iso-8859-1

How can I prevent Flask from returning Latin characters as Unicode representation? For example, for this sort of characters: http://graphemica.com/%C3%91

My FlaskApp performs a SELECT inside a MySQL database, retrieves row by row, adding them to a list, storing the list into a dictionary and finally, returning a JSON.

#### FlaskAPP

```
@app.route("/json")
def show_json():
    avisos_dict = {}
    records_list = []
    query = "SELECT * FROM tjs_stage.avisos"
    cur.execute(query)
    con.commit()
    records = cur.fetchall()
    for row in records:
        records_list.append(row)
    avisos_dict['avisos'] = records_list
    return jsonify(avisos_dict)
```

#### MySQL data

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM tjs_stage.avisos;
+----+---------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| Id | Titulo              | Aviso                           | Creacion            | Modificacion        |
+----+---------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 | PRIMERO AVISO       | MAÑANA EMPIEZAM VACACIONES     | 2016-04-06 18:12:52 | 2016-04-06 18:12:52 |
| 64 | Aviso de Vacaciones | Mañana empezam las vacaciones! | 2016-05-30 17:19:17 | 2016-05-30 17:19:17 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

#### JSON

[image]

Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get string objects instead of Unicode ones from JSON in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956867/how-to-get-string-objects-instead-of-unicode-ones-from-json-in-python)

Comment: The JSON being generated is not only legal, but less vulnerable to encoding problems than an unescaped version would be. JSON is UTF-8, but not all software handles it correctly.

Comment: @Kevin: JSON is a *text* format. It is defined in terms of text (a sequence of Unicode codepoints). It has nothing to do with utf-8 *character encoding* that could be used to *encode* text into a byte sequence. utf-8 is common and it is the default for application/json content-type that is used to transfer a json text over the internet but nothing stops you from saving json text using any character encoding you like on your local disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"Ñ"` and `"\u00d1"` json strings represent the same [U+00D1](http://codepoints.net/U+00D1) Unicode character:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(u'"Ñ"') == json.loads(u'"\\u00d1"')
True
```

Note: the backslash is escaped because it is special inside Python string literals too.

To avoid ascii-encoded json, [set `JSON_AS_ASCII` to `False`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/config/#builtin-configuration-values):

> By default Flask serialize object to ascii-encoded JSON. If this is
>   set to False Flask will not encode to ASCII and output strings as-is
>   and return unicode strings. jsonify will automatically encode it in
>   utf-8 then for transport for instance.

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False


@app.route('/')
def unicode_json():
    return jsonify({'text': u'\xd1'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

To run the server (assuming you saved it to `app.py`):

```
$ python -mpip install flask -U
$ python app.py
```

To test it:

```
$ python -mpip install httpie
$ http --pretty=none :5000
```

Output:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Length: 18
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 31 May 2016 14:54:20 GMT
Server: Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.9

{
    "text": "Ñ"
}
```

@Hareendra Chamara Philips suggests in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531067/how-to-prevent-unicode-representation-for-latin1-characters/37543383?noredirect=1#comment79279060_37543383):

> Alternatively, if some one is using `config.py` and doing `application.config.from_pyfile('config.py')` in `__init__.py`, you can use `JSON_AS_ASCII = False` in the `config.py`.

Comment: It makes sense, but it didn't worked... I still don't have the character as it is from the database.

Comment: @ivanlmj: *"I still don't have the character as it is from the database"* — what does it mean? 1- If you understand the answer then you should understand that the json text (as it is shown in your question) is *already correct* as it is. 2- the second part (about  `JSON_AS_ASCII`) is for your convenience only (so that you could see utf-8 encoded text while debugging instead of Unicode escapes). The representation does not affect the final result (the Unicode object you would get if you parse the json text). 3- try the example from the answer

Comment: Sorry, Sebastian.. Maybe I didn't made myself clear...
I have a MySQL database, with records that contain characters like "ñ","í", for example. I want to display characters like these in a JSON document (character as it is from the database).
Now that you putted an example, I figured out that I didn't had configured JSON_AS_ASCII properly (thanks for the example!). With the right configuration of the parameter, I'm receiving something like this: ["MaÃ±ana empezam las vacaciones!"].. Can I retrieve the character as it is from the database (ñ, for example), instead of represent it?

Comment: @ivanlmj: for the third time: you are already receiving the correct characters. Your issue is how they are displayed. If `JSON_AS_ASCII` is `False` then your environment must understand utf-8 character encoding. Look at the output at the end of the answer—I've copy-pasted it as is from my terminal (that understands utf-8). If your environment does not understand utf-8 then do not set `JSON_AS_ASCII` to `False`, use unicode escapes instead. Again, if you feed the json text to a json parser; the result is *the same* either way. Try it `print(requests.get('http://localhost:5000').json()['text'])`

Comment: I discovered that the browser was displaying "Ã±" instead of "ñ"... Thank you, Sebastian!

Comment: Alternatively, if some one is using config. py and doing application.config.from_pyfile('config.py') in __init__.py, you can use JSON_AS_ASCII = False in the config.py. Works like a charm. Thanks for the answer @jfs