# Loading a json file in python

Tags: python, json, encoding

I've got multiple file to load as JSON, they are all formatted the same way but for one of them I can't load it without raising an exception. This is where you can find the file:

[File](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/riot-api/seed_data/matches3.json)

I did the following code:

```
def from_seed_data_extract_summoners():
   summonerIds = set()
   for i in range(1,11):
       file_name = 'data/matches%s.json' % i
       print file_name
       with open(file_name) as data_file:    
           data = json.load(data_file)
       for match in data['matches']:
           for summoner in match['participantIdentities']:
               summonerIds.add(summoner['player']['summonerId'])
   return summonerIds
```

The error occurs when I do the following: `json.load(data_file)`. I suppose there is a special character but I can't find it and don't know how to replace it. The error generated is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xeb in position 6: invalid continuation byte
```

Do you know how I can get ride of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
json.loads(unicode(data_file.read(), errors='ignore'))
```

or :

```
json.loads(unidecode.unidecode(unicode(data_file.read(), errors='ignore')))
```

(for the second, you would need to install [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode))

Answer (score 2):

1. replace `file_name = 'data/matches%s.json' % i` with file_name = 'data/matches%i.json' % i
2. the right syntax is `data = json.load(file_name)` and not -

   with open(file_name) as data_file:
       data = json.load(data_file)

EDIT:

```
def from_seed_data_extract_summoners():
 summonerIds = set()   
   for i in range(1,11):
        file_name = 'data/matches%i.json' % i
        with open(file_path) as f:
            data = json.load(f, encoding='utf-8')
        for match in data['matches']:
            for summoner in match['participantIdentities']:
                summonerIds.add(summoner['player']['summonerId'])    
    return summonerIds
```

Comment: I did the change and get the following error:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: I will rewrite my answer for you

Comment: Also take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load and https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load @mel

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is trying to force the data into unicode, not just a simple string. You've got some embedded character (probably a space or something not very noticable) that is not able to be forced into unicode.

[How to get string objects instead of Unicode ones from JSON in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956867/how-to-get-string-objects-instead-of-unicode-ones-from-json-in-python)

That is a great thread about making JSON objects more manageable in python.

Answer (score 1):

try :

```
json.loads(data_file.read(), encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: I got the following: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 16260798: ordinal not in range(128)