# Python Unicode Exporting to CSV, removing 'u' character

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, csv, unicode

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import mysql.connector
import json
import pandas as pd

con = mysql.connector.connect(user='',password='',host='',database='')
cursor = con.cursor()
sqlquery = "blahblahblah"
print sqlquery
searches = []
print searches
cursor.execute(sqlquery)
for row in cursor:
    try:
        searchname = row[0].encode("utf-8")
        queryobject = row[1].encode("utf-8")
    except:
        print('Query not found')
    json_dict = json.loads(queryobject)
    searches.append(json_dict)
    print searchs
pd.DataFrame(searches).to_csv('datefile.csv', index=False)
```

Hey, i'm trying to input the above rows into a CSV which is working, however due to what I assume is unicode, the output has a 'u' before every word. The data is fine up until `json_dict = json.loads(queryobject)`. Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is driving me mad.

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956867/how-to-get-string-objects-instead-of-unicode-from-json

Comment: Post the error and stack trace for more help

Comment: thanks wpercy, i did take a look at that earlier but missed the part about trying in python3 - worked a treat, cheers man!

Comment: What does `.encode()` do for you?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `json.loads` when you should be using `json.dumps`.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by changing to python 3.