# python: extract symbol from list and eliminate unicode

Tags: python, list, unicode

I want to create list for symbols as below:

`output = ['A','AA','AABA'...'ZYNE']`

The current output is

```
[
    {u'name': u'Agilent Technologies Inc.', 
     u'symbol': u'A',
     u'iexId': u'2',
     u'date': u'2018-02-12',
     u'type': u'cs',
     u'isEnabled': True},
    {u'name': u'Alcoa Corporation',
     u'symbol': u'AA',
     u'iexId': u'12042',
     u'date': u'2018-02-12',
     u'type': u'cs',
     u'isEnabled': True},
    {u'name': u'Altaba Inc.',
     u'symbol': u'AABA', 
     u'iexId': u'7653',
     u'date': u'2018-02-12',
     u'type': u'cs',
     u'isEnabled': True},
```

I want to eliminate the unicode and just extract symbols out from the current list.

My code is as below

```
import urllib, json
url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/ref-data/symbols"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())
```

I only manage to get one output as `data[0]["symbol"]` which returns `'u'A'` but not in a complete list I want

Comment: I would recommend switching to Python 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get string objects instead of Unicode from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956867/how-to-get-string-objects-instead-of-unicode-from-json)

Comment: @bkollection JSON strings are Unicode. What do you hope to gain by pretending otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
output = [item['symbol'] for item in data]
```

**EDIT:**

If you know that all the `'symbol'` values will be in ASCII just use:

```
output = [str(item['symbol']) for item in data]
```

Otherwise:

```
[item['symbol'].encode('ascii', 'ignore') for item in data]
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to eliminate the unicode `u`?

Comment: @bkcollection Yes, by switching to Python 3.