# Creating a json parsing function with Python

Tags: python

I have been trying to create a function to use as an importable tool for parsing json. here is my code I have so far

```
#json parser
def jsonimporter(file_path , env_to_return):
    import json
    a = open(file_path,"r") #opens and sets the file to read

    data = a.read()         #sets variable to read function
    print(data)

    json_data = json.loads(data) #loads the json data and stores it in json_data variable


    print(json_data)
    json_data.get(env_to_return)

    return json_data
```

What my issue is, is that when I call the function in another file it does not display the parsed json it just displays the json as a a dict in this form;

```
{u'Environments': [{u'Dev': [u'111', u'222']}, {u'Qa': [u'333', u'444']}, {u'prod': [u'555', u'666']}]}
```

The print statements you see are just me trying to double check my answers. 
Also I have passed the call the correct parameters as it prints out the parameters if I ask it too. Thank you for your help!

```
dev = jsonimporter("test2.json","dev")
# dosomething with value
print(value)
```

This is how I called the function

Comment: Parsed JSON *is* a dict.

Comment: Shouldn't you return `json_data.get(env_to_return)`?

Comment: And maybe you need to loop through the `Environments` list, and return the one where the dictionary key matches `env_to_return`.

Comment: BTW, there's no need to call `a.read()` and `json.loads()`, you can just use `json.load(a)`

Comment: And you should close the file after you're done with it. Best is to use `with` so this happens automatically.

Comment: Why do you have a list of dictionaries that each have a different key? It would make more sense to have a single dictionary with each environment as a different key.

Comment: Can you show how you're calling the function and the result you're trying to get?

Comment: ```dev = jsonimporter("test2.json","dev")
# dosomething with value
print(value)``` This is how I am calling the function

Comment: Put it in the question itself.

Comment: When you put code blocks in a question, the code has to start on the line *after* the triple backticks, not the same line. Does the little diagram below the question confuse you? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391467/users-frequently-start-code-blocks-on-the-same-line-as-the-triple-backticks

Comment: @Barmar is on top of this, good advice so far, what I will add is that the imports should go at the top of your file. Following proper style, especially this kind of rule, is important. Also, calling `my_dict.get(one_arg)` is pointless, just use `my_dict[one_arg]` instead.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile The latter depends on what you want to happen when the key isn't found. `get()` will return a default value, `my_dict[one_arg]` will throw an error.

Comment: @Barmar For some reason I thought `.get()` without the default value would behave exactly like `[]`, forgetting that the uh, default default value, is None.

Comment: The `import json` should be at the top of the file, not in the function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the `Environments` property, searching for the dictionary with the key you want.

```
def jsonimporter(file_path, key, env_to_return):
    import json
    with open(file_path,"r") as a:
        json_data = json.load(a)

    for d in json_data[key]:
        if env_to_return in d:
            return d[env_to_return]

dev = jsonimporter("test2.json", "Environments", "dev")
print(dev)
```

Also see [How to get string objects instead of Unicode from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956867/how-to-get-string-objects-instead-of-unicode-from-json) for how to get JSON with ordinary strings instead of Unicode strings in Python 2.

Comment: I like this loop for the answer however, could I used file_path instead of 'environments' because this is for a utility function and the 'Environments' is specific to this particular json

Comment: `file_path` is the filename, not the name of the key in the dictionary.

Comment: Why is the parameter called `env_to_return` if this function isn't specifically about environments?

Comment: You could make that key another parameter to the function. I've updated the answer to show how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final answer I got.

```
def get_multiple_envs_using_jsonimporter(file_path , env_list):
    var1 = jsonimporter("test2.json","Dev")
    var2 = jsonimporter("test2.json","Qa")

    full_list=[]
    full_list.append(var1)
    full_list.append(var2)
    print(full_list)
    # for each env
    # var = jsonimporter(file_path, env)
    # add environment+accounts to list_to_return
    # dev = jsonimporter("test2.json","Dev")









def jsonimporter(file_path , env_to_return):
    a = open(file_path,"r") #opens and sets the file to read

    data = a.read()         #sets variable to read function
    # print(data)

    json_data = json.loads(data) #loads the json data and stores it in json_data variable


    for env in json_data["Environments"]:
        if env_to_return in env:
            return env[env_to_return]
        else:
             print('Not Found')
```

I just appended the variables to the list that called the first function from.