# Optimal way to count the number of keys (and sub keys) in a dict

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a python dict (read from a json file) like the one below:

```
{ 'a' : 
    { 'b' : 
        { 'c': 3, 
          'd': 4} 
    } 
}
```

What is the best way to identify the total number of keys, including sub-keys? In the above example the desired answer would be 4 (`'a','b','c','d'`). Is there a way to do this without just creating a `for` loop and iterating through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`object_hook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=object_hook#json.load) parameter that `json.load()` and `json.loads()` accept to just watch what is being decoded and count the number of keys in each dictionary.

The optional `object_hook` parameter is a function that will be called with the result of any JSON object literal decoded (a `dict`).

I got the idea of doing this from @Mike Brennan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6633651/355230) to another (Python 2) JSON-related question [How to get string objects instead of Unicode from JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956867/how-to-get-string-objects-instead-of-unicode-from-json) — which, as I said initially, is that using `object_hook` is a convenient way to "watch" what's being loaded by the `json.loads()` function.

```
import json


def count_keys(json_repr):
    count = 0

    def _decode_dict(a_dict):
        nonlocal count
        count += len(a_dict)
        return {}  # Return value doesn't matter.

    json.loads(json_repr, object_hook=_decode_dict)  # Return value ignored.
    return count



json_str = '''\
{ "a" :
    { "b" :
        { "c": 3,
          "d": 4}
    }
}'''

print(count_keys(json_str))  # -> 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use recursion:

```
def key_num(d):
   return sum(not isinstance(b, dict) or 1 + key_num(b) for b in d.values())

data = {'a': {'b': {'c': 3, 'd': 4}}}
print(key_num(data))
```

Output:

```
4
```

Comment: Appears that it's creating a `for` loop and iterating through…